# How can I make $E\subseteq F$ vertical?

Tags: math-mode, vertical-alignment

I am wondering whether anyone knows how to type `$E \subset F$` vertical. That is `$E$` is on the top then right below it is `$\cap$`, and below which is `$F$`.

Comment: Without a little more context about where you want this sort of construction, it's hard to tell what would be the best way to build it... Could you explain _where_ you would use such a vertical stack of symbols?

Comment: You can mark inline code with backticks : `\``

Comment: @Seamus, yes I want to use it within "$" and "$".

Comment: Could you give an _example_ of where you want to use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on Seamus answer, here is a marcro that only uses TeX-ish primitives. It should work in any math context, and requires `\usepackage{graphicx}`.

```
\newcommand{\vrel}[3]{
\vcenter{\halign{\hfill##\hfill\cr
\ensuremath{#1}\cr
\rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{\ensuremath{#2}}\cr
\ensuremath{#3}\cr
}}}
```

Usage:

```
\vrel{E}{\subseteq}{F}
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this the sort of thing you had in mind?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{l}
  $E$\\
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{270}{$\subseteq$}\\
  $F$
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: stacked subset]

Note I used `\subseteq` to show that this can work with all relations.

Comment: You could use `array` instead of `tabular` to simplify the writing.

Comment: @Seamus and Gonzalo Medina, Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: @Seamus, it seems that I couldn't put these codes in my surrounding text.

Comment: @Anand that's why you need to tell us how you want to use this thing so we can tailor the solution...

Comment: @Seamus, I see. Thank you so much! :-)