# Designing a new mathematical operator

Tags: symbols, math-operators

We all know that `\binom{n}{r}` in math mode renders the binomial coefficient. For the purposes of a note, I am TeXing up, I am interested in designing a new math operator.

Suppose I called that operator as `\bil{}{}`, I would like the following input `\bil{n}{r}` to give `<n,r>`.

Can anyone please help me with how I would do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
\newcommand\bil[2]{%
  \mathord{\left<#1,#2\right>}%
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, can we replace `\left<` by `\langle`. I think `\langle` looks good right?

Comment: @KannappanSampath If you wish, but I believe `\left<` will come out as `\langle`. Do you see a difference (apart from the fact that `\left<` can grow)?

Comment: (Firstly, I agree with your code. It looks much better with `\left<` than with `\langle`.)

Answer (score 3):

Someting like this will work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*{\bil}[2]{\ensuremath{\langle #1,#2\rangle}}

\begin{document}

Text Text \bil{4}{11} Text Text or \bil{m}{k} even $a=\bil{u}{r}$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Yours works just as fine. Minor Beautification: `\left<` and `\right>` works well when I tried. Thank you for the answer. +1

Comment: You are right, it's better, especially if you want the angle to stretch.

Comment: @PeterBreitfeld Please, have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro about `\ensuremath`.

Comment: @egreg, thank you for this interesting link.

Comment: The "use-`\ensuremath`-only-when-really-needed" campaign is still going on. :)