# How do I make the minus symbol less heavy (or plus more so)

Tags: math-mode, symbols

I've made little superscript plus and minus signs for something by defining

```
\newcommand{\minus}[1]{{#1}^{\scalebox{0.8}{-}}}
\newcommand{\plus}[1]{{#1}^{\scalebox{0.6}{\!+}}}
```

the problem is that compared to the plus, the minus looks really heavy. See for yourselves:
[image: Stupid + and -]

I think I'd rather have a heavier plus. Any thoughts? (other than that I should be less anal)

Comment: Your plus and minus should be in math mode here, which in particular means that the minus is not a minus: you've got a hyphen. Try `\newcommand{\minus}[1]{{#1}^{\scalebox{0.8}{$-$}}}`

Comment: Oh, weird. That's some strange behavior.

Comment: Alos ypu _really_ don't want to use `\scalebox` If you had just use \pi^- and \pi++ they would naturally be smaller size from teh scriptstyle font. By using a box command you go out of math mode so back to text size and then have to shrink by hand.

Answer (score 11):

You should use math mode not text mode with shrinking via the graphics driver.

```
\newcommand{\minus}[1]{{#1}^{-}}
\newcommand{\plus}[1]{{#1}^{+}}
```

This will make a minus sign not a hyphen, and be naturally smaller because of the superscript.

Comment: Would `\ensuremath` be useful in the definitions for `\minus` and `\plus`?

Comment: well perhaps except really you should know if you are in math or not. definitions like `\alpha` or the primitive  `^` superscripting operation only work in math mode, and TeX really expects the author to maintain that distinction. Blurring it with `\ensuremath` doesn't always make things clearer.

Comment: @JohnReed See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/575 for that question.

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the comments and link. Always learning...

Comment: This is, of course, how I did it in the first place. The badness of how they look is what motivated the use of `\scalebox`. I'd rather hack it to make it look how I want than do it properly so that it doesn't.

Comment: You didn't say that you had tried that, It has the distinct advantage of taking the - and + from the same, mathematical font such that the - will be the same size and aligned with the bar of the + in almost all fonts. Using a hyphen character from a text font is just wrong, and a + from a text font may look OK, but isn't ideal either.