# How to use suggestive variable names in math?

Tags: math-mode

I want to use suggestive variable and function names in math like the in the following:

> result = f(input)

or

> accumulator = sum(inputs)

I want the formula to stand out in relation to the surrounding text. So if I use the following:

`\(\mbox{result} = F(input)\)`

it doesn't work because then "result" looks just like the normal surrounding text, while "F(input)" is italicized in math mode. So how can I make the "result" be also italicized correctly and consistently. Maybe I shouldn't use math mode at all but just normal mode and italicize the whole? But I intend it to be a logical unit within the text.

Answer (score 6):

I would probably use bold-upright for multi-letter names so `\mathbf{result}=f(\mathbf{inputs})` you don't want to use math-italic for multi-letter names, the spacing is all wrong, but you could use text italic so:`\mathit{input}`

Depending on the document type you have other ways of making equations stand out from the surrounding text, different offset, or box them, or add colour or....

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that "result" and "input" occur several times in the document, you could define the macros

```
\newcommand*{\Result}{\ensuremath{\mathit{result}}}
\newcommand*{\Input}{\ensuremath{\mathit{input}}}
```

and then use them in math expressions such as

```
$\Result = f(\Input)$
```

but also in running text without having to switch to math mode first.

If you want to change the look of the variable names from italics to upright, say, you'd only have to change the `\mathit` instructions in the definitions to `\mathrm`, and the change would show up everywhere in the document.

At any rate, I wouldn't use `\mbox` in the definitions of the macros, as doing so "freezes" the size (at `\textstyle` sizing) and thus precludes the easy of the variable names in subscripts, where you'd want `\scriptstyle` (or even `\scriptscriptstyle`) sizing.

Comment: Why go into math mode via `\ensuremath{}` only to go back to text mode via `\text{}`?

Comment: What's wrong in using `\mathit{result}` instead of that complicated construction? This will ensure italics, while your macro, if used when the current font is italic, will produce upright text.

Comment: @PeterGrill - the idea was to make the `\Result` and `\Input` macros work equally well in text mode and math mode, so that the user won't have to remember to switch into math mode when the variable names are used in running text.

Comment: @egreg -- Excellent point about `\emph` generating an undesirable effect if the current mode happens to be italics (as could happen in the statement of a theorem). I'll change the code to correct this potential pitfall.

Comment: @Mico: I understand `\ensuremath{}` even though others disagree :-) as in [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro), but `\text{}` puts you in text mode, so you could just use `\text{}` without going into math mode first as `\text{}` works in text mode as well.

Comment: I'm thinking about using just plain text mode and \emph. Any idea how to convert the "=" to a math equals sign?

Comment: @Mr.Roland -- If the expression you need to typeset is indeed an equation, as in `\Result = f(\Input)`, it's best to use mathmode explicitly: doing so will not only generate math-appropriate amounts of whitespace around the `=` symbols automatically but also take care of math-appropriate (i) spacing around the parentheses and (ii) line breaking methods. Separately, to ensure that any variable names are always set in upright-roman mode, use `\mathrm` in the definitions of these variable names.