# Font-independent convention for multi-letter variables in math mode

Tags: math-mode, typography

For several years now, I have always used `\mathit` to display variables that have more than one letter, to ensure proper kerning:

```
\fbox{$foo = f(jazz)$} vs. \fbox{$\mathit{foo} = f(\mathit{jazz})$}
```

[image: first example]

I see that this has been suggested [several](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67109/how-to-use-suggestive-variable-names-in-math/67117) [times](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6087/two-letter-variable-names) here as well.

However I would now like to update my document and use the Euler math fonts.  In this setup, the default mathematical font has upright letters, and suddenly, all my `\mathit` have become wrong. I do not even know how to fix it:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{eulervm}
\begin{document}
\fbox{$foo = f(jazz)$} vs. \fbox{$\mathit{foo} = f(\mathit{jazz})$}
                       vs. \fbox{$\mathrm{foo} = f(\mathrm{jazz})$}
                       vs. \fbox{$\mbox{foo} = f(\mbox{jazz})$}
\end{document}
```

[image: second example]

Surely there must be a way to tell LaTeX "here is a block of text to treat as a single name", disabling the spacing for the implicit multiplication, and without forcing any particular font, so that the formula can be rendered nicely independently of the mathematical font I later decide to use?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean with “wrong”: `\mathit` uses the italic text font. You should have used a personal command such as `\mlv` with `\newcommand{\mlv}[1]{\mathit{#1}}`, so now you could simply change the definition into `\newcommand{\mlv}[1]{#1}`

Comment: By "wrong" I mean one should never use `\mathit` to mean "Dear TeX, do not space these letters like in a product" assuming the font is in italics.  I'm presently using a macro called `\var`, and defined exactly like your `\mlv` (i.e., it currently expands to #1 if I use Euler fonts), the result is not fully satisfactory. For instance with Euler math there is too much space between `j` and `azz` in `$jazz$`.

Comment: Euler math letters are not made for multiletter identifiers.

Comment: @adl -- you say 'By "wrong" I mean one should never use \mathit to mean "Dear TeX, do not space these letters like in a product" assuming the font is in italics.'  this is a misconception.  what `\mathit` means is what egreg says: '\mathit uses the italic text font.'.  this is different from what knuth defines as "math italic", and it could be considered a bad naming decision in latex.  however, quoting from lamport, p. 51, "You should use `\mathit` for multiletter symbols in formulas".  seems like `eulervm` is doing the wrong thing.