# Shortcuts and/or user-defined shortcuts for math symbols in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, macros, packages

I am very new to being able to use LaTeX to type up mathematical papers, and I just got my "system" set up. Currently I have installed TexWorks, and MikTex, and I have put together a 'hello world' article which seems to run well.

I have also used the syntax "\usepackage{amsmath}" and "\usepackage{amssymb}" in the beginning of my .tex file to write math symbols, only because some online tutorial said so.

My question is, firstly, are those the only packages I need to use for writing math, and secondly, I remember reading about some shortcuts(?) that can be used for writing math symbols, and/or user defined shortcuts that can be 'set' in the beginning so as to reduce the amount of LaTeX code needed to write mathematical symbols. However, I do not know if this is true, and if it is, how to go about 'installing' such a thing.

Does such a thing exist? Am I able to make my own shortcuts?

Thanks!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You surely can define your shortcuts; indeed you *should*.

Let's make some examples. Suppose your document is full of Fourier transforms, for which you need a fancy F. Instead of writing every time

```
$\mathcal{F}(f)$
```

it's surely better to define a new command, say

```
\newcommand{\FT}{\mathcal{F}}
```

(choose any name you like), so that you can type

```
$\FT(f)$
```

and get the same result as before, with a big bonus! If you change your mind about the notation, you can simply modify the definition.

Another example. The "gradient" operator is not predefined; so you might want to have a command for it:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}
```

A different one; my preferred notation for vectors is, say, `\mathbf{v}`. However, since conventions are different, I never type vectors in that way, but prefer to have

```
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
```

for the same reason as before; I might change my mind and want to modify the appearance, say for using bold italic; this would be accomplished just by saying

```
\usepackage{bm}
```

and changing the above into

```
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\bm{#1}}
```

How do you organize this? Here's an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % input encoding UTF-8

% Useful packages
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}

% add all the packages you need

% Personal definitions

\newcommand{\FT}{\mathcal{F}}      % Fourier transform operator
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}  % gradient
\newcommand{\vect}[1]{\mathbf{#1}} % vectors and matrices

\begin{document}

...

\end{document}
```

Add definitions while you find that they are useful for distinguishing logical units of your document.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of different packages, but there's no need to include them all: use only these which you need.

For example, package `wrapfig` allows you to add floating tables and images. You may need `multicol` if you'll deicide to switch between different amount of columns in your document. Use `cite` to make cites to bibliography more pretty. Use `longtable` if you wish to put multipage tables into your document. `amsfonts` consists some symbols you may need. `wasysym` consists a lot of other symbols usefull in some cases. Package `array` allows you to put into tables such instruction like `m{}, b{}, >{}, <{}, !{}` etc.

And here some things from my style file that maybe will help you:

```
\newcommand{\Ang}{\mbox{\rm\AA}}                % Angstom
\newcommand{\arr}{\ensuremath{\,\rightarrow\,}} % right arrow
\newcommand{\Arr}{\ensuremath{\,\Rightarrow\,}} % wide arrow
\newcommand{\aver}[1]{{<\!\!#1\!\!>}}           % average
\newcommand{\B}[1]{\ensuremath{\mathbf{#1}}}    % bold for matrix & so on
\newcommand{\bra}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle #1|}}  % bra-vector
\newcommand{\bracket}[1]{\ensuremath{\langle #1|#1\rangle}}     % square of state vector
\newcommand{\cket}[1]{\ensuremath{#1\rangle}}   % cet-vector when multiplying to bra-
\newcommand{\const}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{const}}} % constant
\renewcommand{\C}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{C}}}    % another constant
\newcommand{\D}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{D}}}      % 
\newcommand{\ddotvec}[1]{%\ddot{\vec{#1}}}      % second dv/dt
    \savebox{\hght}{$\vec{#1}$}\ddot{\raisebox{0pt}[.8\ht\hght]{$\vec{#1}$}}}
\newcommand{\degr}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}         % degree
\newcommand{\diam}{\ensuremath{\varnothing\,}}  % diameter
\newcommand{\diver}{\mathop{\mathrm{div}}\nolimits} % divergence
\newcommand{\dotvec}[1]{%                       % dv/dt
    \savebox{\hght}{$\vec{#1}$}\dot{\raisebox{0pt}[.8\ht\hght]{$\vec{#1}$}}}
\newcommand{\dpartder}[2]{\dfrac{\partial^2 #1}{\partial #2^2}} % 2nd partial derivative
\newcommand{\e}{\mathop{\mathrm e}\nolimits}    % exp
\newcommand{\E}{\mathcal{E}}                    % electromoving force
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\varepsilon}            % epsilon by russian tradition
\newcommand{\frc}[2]{\raisebox{2pt}{$#1$}\big/\raisebox{-3pt}{$#2$}}    % fraction
\newcommand{\F}{\ensuremath{\mathop{\mathfrak F}}\nolimits}     % pretty F
\newcommand{\FT}[1]{\mathcal{F}(#1)}            % fourier
\renewcommand{\H}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{H}}}    % 
\newcommand{\IFT}[1]{\mathcal{F}^{-1}(#1)}      % reverse fourier
\renewcommand{\ge}{\geqslant}                   % >=
\newcommand{\grad}{\mathop{\mathrm{grad}}\nolimits} % gradient
\newcommand{\I}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{I}}}      % short for integral
\newcommand{\ind}[1]{_{\text{\scriptsize #1}}}  % down index
\newcommand{\indfrac}[2]{\raisebox{2pt}{$\frac{\mbox{\small $#1$}}{\mbox{\small $#2$}}$}} 
\newcommand{\ILT}[1]{\mathop{\mathfrak{L}}\nolimits^{-1}(#1)} % reverse laplas
\newcommand{\Infint}{\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty} % integral by R
\newcommand{\Int}{\int\limits}          % Big integral
\newcommand{\IInt}{\mathop{{\int\!\!\!\int}}\limits}    % Big double integral
\renewcommand{\kappa}{\varkappa}                % kappa in russian traditions
\newcommand{\ket}[1]{\ensuremath{|#1\rangle}}   % cet-vector
\renewcommand{\le}{\leqslant}                   % <=
\newcommand{\ltextarrow}[1]{\ensuremath{\stackrel{#1}\leftarrow}} % left arrow with text above
\newcommand{\lvec}{\overrightarrow}             % long vector
\newcommand{\LT}[1]{\mathop{\mathfrak{L}}\nolimits(#1)} % laplas
\newcommand{\M}{\ensuremath{\mathop{\mathfrak M}\nolimits}} % stellar mass
\newcommand{\mean}[1]{\overline{#1}}            % mean
\newcommand{\med}[1]{\mathop{\mathrm{med} #1}\nolimits} % median
\newcommand{\Oint}{\oint\limits}                % Big circular integral
\renewcommand{\P}{\ensuremath{\mathfrak{P}}}    % 
\newcommand{\partder}[2]{\dfrac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}} % partial der.
\renewcommand{\phi}{\varphi}                    % phi in russuan
\newcommand{\R}{\ensuremath{\mathbb{R}}} % rat. numbers
\newcommand{\rev}[1]{\frac{1}{#1}}              % reverse
\newcommand{\rot}{\mathop{\mathrm{rot}}\nolimits} % curve (rotor in russian)
\newcommand{\rtextarrow}[1]{\ensuremath{\stackrel{#1}\rightarrow}} % rightarrow with text
\newcommand{\Sum}{\sum\limits}  % sum
\newcommand{\sinc}{\mathop{\mathrm{sinc}}\nolimits} % integral sinus
\newcommand{\Tr}{\mathop{\mathrm{Tr}}\nolimits} % matrix trace
\newcommand{\veci}{{\vec\imath}}                % i-ort
\newcommand{\vecj}{{\vec\jmath}}                % j-ort
\newcommand{\veck}{{\vec{k}}}                   % k-ort
\newcommand{\when}[2]{\settowidth{\myflt}{\scriptsize $#2$}% vert. line with limits
    \ensuremath{\left.{#1}\right|_{#2}\hspace{-\myflt}\,}}
\newcommand{\ZT}[1]{\mathop{\mathcal{Z}}\nolimits(#1)} % Z-transform
\newcommand{\IZT}[1]{\mathop{\mathcal{Z}}\nolimits^{-1}(#1)} % rev. Z
```

Comment: This piece of code contains lots of things that are very bad. First of all, all `\ensuremath`, `\aver` should be made using `\langle...\rangle` etc. Generally look into `amsmath` and `mathtools` documentation, especially on macros `\DeclareMathOperator`, `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` and `\DeclarePairedDelimiterX`.

Comment: @tohecz, For example?

Comment: Thanks Eddy, but I have many questions - 1) first of all, 'where' do I copy/paste all of this? I am very new to TexWorks. Do I just put it in the top of my .tex page? 2) How do you 'add' packages?

Comment: @Eddy_Em Your definition of `\F` is plainly wrong. Just try writing `$\F\mathfrak{F}$` to see why. I fully agree with tohecz that all `\ensuremath` are wrong. `amsmath` makes available `\xrightarrow` that does much better than your `\ltextarrow`; `\ind` may be simply `_\text{#1}`; `\iint` is better than your `\IInt`. I could continue.

Comment: @egreg, some of my definitions were made so because I didn't like standard behaviour. Also some definitions mirrors russian math traditions. @Mohammad, read carefully comments of egreg & tohecz. About including: usually such things gathered in user-style: simple `.sty` file which then included into documents by `\usepackage`.

Comment: @Eddy_Em I would suggest you to visit us [in the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41/tex-latex-and-friends) so that we discuss which definitions are matter of style and preferences and which yield to wrong results. I'm really interested in knowing more details.

Comment: I'm assuming the problems pointed out with the use of `\ensuremath` refer to [issues when `\ensuremath` is used with macros taking arguments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34837/15665) primarily?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer about the following part of the above question:

```
I remember reading about some shortcuts(?) that can be used for writing math symbols
Does such a thing exist?
```

Yes, some shortcuts do exist:

- `\to` is a shortcut for `\rightarrow`
- `\gets` is a shortcut for `\leftarrow`
- `\implies` from package `amsmath` is a shortcut for `\Longrightarrow`
- `\ne` is a shortcut for `\not=`
- `\iff` is a longer version of `\Leftrightarrow`
- `\O` is a shortcut for `\emptyset`

Comment: I do have a couple of comments: `\implies` needs `amsmath`; `\neq` is an abbreviation of `\not=` (there is no `\eq` in a standard setup), and `\O` is a text mode macro to get a nordic barred O, so whatever package is redefining that to `\emptyset` is playing with fire.

Comment: @campa I looked up the string ' or \' on http://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols ; and `\emptyset` indeed differs from `\varnothing`. I came on this page looking for shortcuts for `\varepsilon`, which I thought had existed.

Comment: @campa thanks for your comments.

Comment: Some were somehow documented in comments of tex.SE: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/141454/define-a-shortcut-to-rightarrow-in-plain-tex#comment319793_141454