# \DeclareMathOperator: wrong space when the operator is followed by a binary operator

Tags: spacing, math-operators

[In this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/95732/18401) to the question [Shortcuts and/or user-defined shortcuts for math symbols in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/95718/18401), it is advised to denote the gradient with `\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}`.

But this is suboptimal (wrong space) compared to `\mathrm{grad}` when the operator is followed by a binary operator (the same with ∇ instead of "grad"), as shown by the following MWE (where only equations ≡ 0 mod 3 are okay):

```
\documentclass[convert,varwidth=4cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
%
\DeclareMathOperator{\grad}{grad}
\DeclareMathOperator{\Div}{div}
\DeclareMathOperator{\curl}{curl}
%
\DeclareMathOperator{\nablaop}{\nabla}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
  \Div  F & = \grad         \cdot  F \\
  \Div  F & = \grad{}       \cdot  F \\
  \Div  F & = \mathrm{grad} \cdot  F \\
  \curl F & = \grad         \wedge F \\
  \curl F & = \grad{}       \wedge F \\
  \curl F & = \mathrm{grad} \wedge F \\
  \Div  F & = \nablaop      \cdot  F \\
  \Div  F & = \nablaop{}    \cdot  F \\
  \Div  F & = \nabla        \cdot  F \\
  \curl F & = \nablaop      \wedge F \\
  \curl F & = \nablaop{}    \wedge F \\
  \curl F & = \nabla        \wedge F
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there a way to make `\DeclareMathOperator`'s behavior okay when the operator is followed by a binary operator?

Comment: you can always make a mathop  into  a mathord by  adding `{}` as in `{\grad}`

Comment: Are you willing to accept a syntax such as `\grad{f}`, `\grad{\cdot F}` or `\grad{\wedge F}`?

Comment: @egreg Well... `\grad{f}` is okay but `\grad{\cdot F}` and `\grad{\wedge F}` are conceptually suspect :)

Comment: If you are sure that `\grad` is always followed by a certain fixed set of tokens, if not by a variable, it can be arranged, I guess.

Comment: @egreg Who knows what mathematicians are able to imagine?! ;)

Comment: I think that you could define `\grad` and `\gradop`, since why to use operator if you are not applying on some variable?

Comment: @Sigur That would be a possibility but not the most handy (see egreg's answer) and, overall, having different macros for the same mathematical object is conceptually questionable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure that `\grad` will be followed by a fixed (but easily extendable) set of binary operators, this should work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\DeclareMathOperator{\gradop}{grad}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% the list of admissible binary operators
\tl_const:Nn \c_denis_grad_ops_tl { \cdot \wedge }

\NewDocumentCommand{\grad}{}
 {
  \gradop
  \peek_after:Nw \denis_grad_check:
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \denis_grad_check:
 {
  \tl_map_inline:Nn \c_denis_grad_ops_tl
   {% if the token matches one in the list, issue {\!}
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNT \l_peek_token ##1 { \tl_map_break:n { {\!} } }
   }
 } 

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\grad F \\
\mathop{\mathrm{grad}} F\\
\grad \cdot F \\
\mathrm{grad}\cdot F \\
\grad \wedge F \\
\mathrm{grad}\wedge F 
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If a binary operator in the list follows, we issue `{\!}` that fixes the spacing: the thin space between the operator and the empty atom is nullified by `\!` and the empty atom will provide the required bit for the spacing around binary operators.

A slightly different version with an interface for adding binary operators; the initial declaration

```
\OperatorBinary{\cdot,\wedge} % initialize
```

should go in the class, together with instructions such as

> You can define operator names that behave well when followed by binary operation symbols with
>
> ```
> \DeclareMathOperatorX{<cs>}{<name>}
> ```
>
> for example
>
> ```
> \DeclareMathOperatorX{\grad}{grad}
> ```
>
> to be used like `\grad f` or else like `\grad\cdot F`. The predefined list of admissible binary operators includes `\cdot` and `\wedge`, but it can be augmented by saying in the preamble, for instance,
>
> ```
> \OperatorBinary{\times}
> ```
>
> (the argument can be a list like in the initial declaration which is `\OperatorBinary{\cdot,\wedge}`. No operator of this type is predefined, use `\DeclareMathOperatorX` for defining the one you'll be using.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\DeclareMathOperatorX}{mm}
 {
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{}
   {
    \operatorname{#2}
    \peek_after:Nw \denis_opx_check:
   }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\OperatorBinary}{m}
 {
  \clist_gput_right:Nn \g_denis_opx_binary_clist { #1 }
 }

\clist_new:N \g_denis_opx_binary_clist
\cs_new_protected:Nn \denis_opx_check:
 {
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \g_denis_opx_binary_clist
   {
    \token_if_eq_meaning:NNT \l_peek_token ##1 { \clist_map_break:n { {\!} } }
   }
 } 
\ExplSyntaxOff

\OperatorBinary{\cdot,\wedge} % initialize
\DeclareMathOperatorX{\grad}{grad}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\grad F \\
\mathop{\mathrm{grad}} F\\
\grad \cdot F \\
\mathrm{grad}\cdot F \\
\grad \wedge F \\
\mathrm{grad}\wedge F 
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! But what I'm working on is for a journal of math and I can't anticipate all the operators (gradient, divergence, curl, etc.) and all the binary operations the authors will be able to use :)

Comment: @DenisBitouzé I added an interface for defining new special operators and for augmenting the list of symbols possibly following them.

Comment: Wow, *very* interesting! Finally, I will provide this nice feature in the class :)

Comment: Interestingly, with`\DeclareMathOperatorX{\gradn}{\nabla}`, `\gradn` and `\nabla` have same output if involved in binary operations (e.g. `\gradn \cdot F` and `\nabla \cdot F`) but not if applied to applications (the interspace is bigger e.g. in `\gradn F` than in `\nabla F`). Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: Ooops, sorry for the noise: I should have compared `\gradn` and `\mathop{\nabla}`.

Answer (score 7):

`\DeclareMathOperator` makes a `\mathop` atom, which are designed for use as prefix functions. In contexts where they are not being used as a prefix application, such as the higher order composition here you can always make a `\mathord` atom by surrounding with braces, `{\grad}` which will have the same spacing as `\mathrm{grad}`

Comment: Tomorrow if you get voting reversal, I am to be blamed ;)