# Is it possible to redefine \alpha this way?

Tags: macros

I was thinking about doing something crazy, namely, I want to define a "newcommand" by

```
\renewcommand{\alpha}{\ensuremath{\alpha}}
```

so that later in text mode I can just do `\alpha` instead of `$\alpha$` (The actual macro will have `\xspace` in it, but let's ignore that.).

The question is, how do I let the system know, when it replace `\alpha` by `\ensuremath{\alpha}` to use the "built-in" macro `\alpha`, instead of the renewed one, and thus not stuck in an infinite loop?

Or, is there a way to make sure the macro only "expand" once?

Comment: Don't moan when you find that the result of `\alpha-\beta` is different from what you'd expected. There's no reason why math symbold should be used in text without proper markup.

Comment: Well, that's what I expected, so I will take care. You see lots of the time people want to write `\alpha`-male or `\epsilon`-neighborhood, `\delta`-ball etc. And there is no easy solution for that.

Comment: For alpha-male, you can always write it in full text. For `\epsilon`-neighborhood, you really should write it with dollars : see for example the difference between `$\epsilon$'-neighborhood` (expansion of your macro) and `$\epsilon'$-neighborhood` (what you probably want to write). The point is : if it is always the same math symbol with the same text, you can encapsulate all in a macro. But if it may vary, you should stick with math markup. You can also see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro.

Comment: @T.Verron I understand that primes are funny and will take care of that. I will put it in math mode whenever it is not a single letter.

Comment: @hyh Yes, there is an easy solution for that: `$\alpha$-male`. But, since it's a technical term in a non mathematical field, probably `\alphamale` with a proper definition would be preferable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but here's how anyway

```
\let\oldalpha\alpha
\renewcommand{\alpha}{\ensuremath{\oldalpha}}
```

Your queried approach would result in an infinite loop.  The `\let` essentially makes an *alias* for the former meaning of `\alpha` which will allow you to redefine it later.