# What is the capital Greek letter for tau?

Tags: greek

I would like to typeset the capital Greek letter for tau. I used `\Tau`, but I got error for that:

> Undefined control sequence.

My preamble is

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

I was wondering what goes wrong?

Comment: The capital "tau" is nothing other than a capital "t"; see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_alphabet). That's why TeX does not define a control sequence associated for capital "tau". Similarly, capital "alpha" is "A", capital "beta" is "B", etc.

Comment: But I need capital "t" to represent another different quantity.

Comment: Then use different font family for your "Tau"

Comment: `\mathcal{T}` will give you a capital tau that doesn't just look like a regular T.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

since many of the greek uppercase letters have the same shape as latin letters, they were not separately provided for tex, for two reasons:

- to save space (which was a real consideration in 1980);
- because it wouldn't be possible to tell the difference between the two shapes.

the first reason is no longer relevant, of course, but the second is.

go ahead and define your own:

```
\newcommand{\Tau}{\mathrm{T}}
```

for latex, or

```
\def\Tau{{\rm T}}
```

if you're using plain tex.

Answer (score 10):

As barbara suggested

```
\newcommand\Tau{\mathrm{T}}
```

will typeset Roman T.

When loading

```
\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand\Tau{\mathcal{T}}% Caligraphic T for example
```

You can access more symbols for your purpose.
At [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/symbols.html) you can find most common symbols and identify them from handwritten image.

Comment: A good read [when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro)

Comment: OK. If you know what you're doing there's no problem. When you don't there might be trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing goes wrong. `:)`

Quoting from the `The Not So Short Introduction to LATEX2e` (ver 5.01) - p. 56

> There is no uppercase Alpha, Beta etc. defined in LATEX2e because it looks the same
>   as a normal roman A, B...

Comment: Interesting how "they" didn't do the "semantic thing" in this particular case. After all, `\Tau` *means* something substantially different from 'T'.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough: What about the capital Cyrillic Te (written "T") - is it the same as the capital Greek tau which it is based on?  I'm no expert on lettering, but it seems unremarkable to me that different alphabets can share the same glyphs.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough however, these two letters use the same symbol and in the same way (`\mathord`). Which means that they are identical for LaTeX. And not only for LaTeX, they are identical for a mathematician as well. For linguists, they are different, but you don't use `$\Tau$` as a lingust, right? :)

Comment: @CharlesStewart Oh, yes, the glyphs are the same, but the semantic context is different, and we are always told (correctly, IMO) to "do LaTeX things semantically"

Comment: @Brent.Longborough barbara described the shortage of space in the early days of tex; latex2e had a similar experience (remember, it appeared when many people were using rather small 286-based machines) -- there are lots of oddities about the kernel's coding, many of them simply to save csnames.  in that circumstance, there's no surprise that there's no "semantic" \Tau dating from the early days, and nowadays people who care about these things are using entirely different set-ups, so there's little incentive now, either.

Comment: @Brent.Longborough - There is some sense to what you say, e.g., Unicode represents T as different code points in its Latin, Greek, and Cyrillic code tables.  Though note that if you use Luatex or Xetex, you have the Unicode ontology as part of Latex: just choose a maths font with enough characters and use the Unicode in your Latex source file.  And I'm not sure there's a real problem: Unicode's identical glyphs for different code points is often a nuisance.

Comment: In a sense, my previous comments, were, I admit, "mild trolling". Some of @CharlesStewart 's "nuisance" is, occasionally, necessary: for example, for `\MakeLowerCase{}` to behave correctly.

Comment: @CharlesStewart -- the unicode "identical glyphs ... nuisance" does have some positive side effects, including the ability to correctly alphabetize the base language for the script without jumping through hoops.