# Macro with environmental dependent output

Tags: math-mode, macros, equations, conditionals

I'm trying to develop a macro that gives two different outputs depending on whether it is in math mode (i.e. `$ $`  or `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`) or anywhere else. The reason is that I use a lot of physical variables and molecule names such as e.g. 
`$^{12}$CO(1-0)` and use macros to be able to have them typeset uniformly troughout the text. I use them in normal text as well as math environment. Right now I have two macros one for text:

```
\newcommand{\twCO}{%
$^{12}$CO(1-0)\xspace%
}%
```

and one for math with out the math signs:

```
\newcommand{\twCO}{%
^{12}CO(1-0)%
}% .
```

I would like to come up with something more generic:

```
\newcommand{\twCO}{%
\ifinmathmode%
 ^{12}CO(1-0)%
\else%
 $^{12}$CO(1-0)\xspace%
}
```

Searching quite some time on TeX and a prominent search provider, I could not find a satisfying answer to this, only more complex constructions to do the check. But I'd like to ask if someone is aware of a straightforward check to see which environment one is in?

EDIT:

After trying out the options given in the answer and comments below, I found that the 
easiest and best setup for my situation in which I also want the new commands to respect boldface and italic (which I figured out after I asked...) from the environment is to use `text` from `amsmath` which was pointed out by @egreg in the comments to his answer. Thus the best solution to my question is to use something like:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\twCO}{\text{\textsuperscript{12}CO}}
```

To set Isotopes however `mhchem`, which was pointed out in the comments, is really usefull.

However for someone that want to test for math mode, the second answer is working well. Or one could use `\ensuremath`, also mentioned in the comments. This however does not respect boldface or italics from the environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use `$^12$CO(1-0)` in text mode and `^12CO(1-0)` in math mode you surely get *different results. The letters `CO` change shape and the hyphen becomes a minus sign in math mode.

If you really want uniform results in text and math mode, do

```
\newcommand{\twCO}{\textnormal{\textsuperscript{12}CO(1-0)}}
```

This actually means using text mode also in math.

Add `\xspace` if you really want it; I never recommend it.

Comment: Great thanks that was quick and easy, I was not aware of the `\textnormal` command and was searching something way to complicated. Just out of curiosity, why would you not use \xspace?

Comment: @Ascurion I don't think it's necessary. Just use `\twCO{}` in text mode.

Comment: Regarding `xspace` see [Drawbacks of xspace](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/22413)

Comment: Thanks for the info! I am really amazed how quick, helpfull and friendly everybody is on TeX.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use `mhchem` in this case? At least it is quite good at typesetting isotopes etc.

Comment: @daleif Possibly, or maybe certainly.

Comment: @dalei thanks for the hint! I actually switched to `mhchem` to do the isotopes and molecule typesetting part and some chemical formulas I wrote by hand. However, my question also included  physical units such as, e.g. L$_{\odot}$ where `mhchem` cant help.

Comment: @egreg I switched the accepted answer since, although your solution is more generic and clean I found in the end that it ignores the surrounding format and thus does not come out correctly in e.g. section headers, as I explained in my Question. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: @Ascurion I don't think this should respect the format (boldface, in particular) since it's a symbol; however, just use `\textup` instead of `\textnormal` or, if you want also to respect italic, just `\text` (requires `amsmath`).

Comment: @egreg I guess you are right! But in my field, Astronomy, its quite common to use molecules in the section headers and they are normally set in boldface as well. I just checked some books to be sure. :) But using `\text` this is working as I intend it too. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

@egreg showed you how to achieve uniformity.  But you also asked about testing whether you were in math mode:

Then you'll want to do something like:

```
\newcommand{\test}{%
  Hello:
  \ifmmode%
    this is math
  \else
    this is not math
  \fi
}
```

Your example command could then be rewritten as

```
% requires `amsmath` for `\text{...}`
\newcommand{\twCO}{%
  \relax
  \ifmmode
    ^{12}\text{CO(1-0)}%
  \else
    $^{12}$CO(1-0)%
  \fi
}
```

Or, as also suggested by egreg,

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\twCO}{%
  \ifmmode
    ^{12}\text{CO(1-0)}%
  \else
    $^{12}$CO(1-0)%
  \fi
}
```

Though before defining macros which test for math mode, [you might want to be aware of various, potential complications](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/34837/22413)

Comment: Put `\relax` before `\ifmmode`; you'll see why if you use `\twCO` as the first element in an `array` cell. Or use `\DeclareRobustCommand`.

Comment: @egreg  Ick!  What's going on?

Comment: @A.Ellet Oh yes thanks, this is what I was frustratingly trying to find. Good to know how to check for math mode. I think I stick to egregs solution for my current application, though, since it is more straight forward in terms of implementation and uniformity for my application in the end.

Comment: @A.Ellett TeX tries to expand the first token in a cell, in order to see if it has to use `\omit` (usually buried in a `\multicolumn` and it is in horizontal mode at the time; so the expansion of `\ifmmode` follows the "false" branch and TeX decides there's no `\omit`. Now it inserts the `$` commanded by `array` and so the input is equivalent to `$$^12...` which gives an error because `$$` in horizontal mode just makes an empty formula and TeX finds `^` outside math mode. The `\relax` is not expandable, so the conditional is not untimely expanded.

Comment: what's wrong with `\ensuremath`?  (not an answer to the question, but neither are many of the options offered so far.)

Comment: @wasteofspace I tried \ensuremath but in my experience this ignores the surrounding environment. Thus, e.g. using an Isotope in a section header renders it not bold.