# Unexpect differences between calling \ifmmode from within a command and outside a command

Tags: math-mode, macros, conditionals

In answering [another question regarding testing for math mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123031/22413), I proposed the following command

```
\newcommand{\testa}{%
  \ifmmode
    ^{12}\text{CO(1-0)}%
  \else
    $^{12}$CO(1-0)%
  \fi
}
```

But @egreg pointed out that I should be writing either:

```
\newcommand{\egrega}{%
  \relax
  \ifmmode
    ^{12}\text{CO(1-0)}%
  \else
    $^{12}$CO(1-0)%
  \fi
}
```

or

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\egregb}{%
  \ifmmode
    ^{12}\text{CO(1-0)}%
  \else
    $^{12}$CO(1-0)%
  \fi
}
```

and proposed I test things out in an `array` environment to see what happens.

```
\[\begin{array}{c}
  \testa
\end{array}\]
```

Sure enough, `\testa` results in the following warning:

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.42   \testa

?
```

whereas the two command `\egrega` and `\egregb` work as expected.

I wasn't happy with just this.  My understanding of robustness is quite shacky.  And, while I've read various posts such as [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4747/22413), I still felt a bit in the dark.

So, I tried a different approach.  I tried writing

```
\[\begin{array}{c}
  \ifmmode{Math}\else{NOT MATH}\fi
\end{array}\]
```

Really, I don't why I did this.  I expected to the same error as with the *faulty version* of the command.  But instead I didn't get an error at all.  Instead, I got the following *unexpected* and *erroneous* result:

[image]

Clearly something is going **very** wrong here, and not in any way I anticipated.  If instead I write

```
\[\begin{array}{c}
  \relax\ifmmode{Math}\else{NOT MATH}\fi
\end{array}\]
```

or precede the `\ifmmode` by anything else to be processed, all seems to go well.

What am I failing to understand here?

Comment: Related: [Correct usage of \ifmmode](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82653) and [\ifmmode doesn't seem to work correctly inside an array environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/27592)

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Both very useful.  So it seems this question should be marked as a duplicate.

Comment: I've closed as a dupe, as you suggest