# How to create a list of symbols where symbols can be used in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, glossaries

I describe complex protocols with lots of variables in different files. The problem is that I might change the variable names later. My idea was to define variable names as Latex commands like `\lengthtree` (instead of writing e.g. `$\ell_t$`). Later I can easily change `\lengthtree` to `$L_t$` by just redefine the latex command.

Now I want to create a list of symbols and I am searching for a possibility to create it automatically. I give the glossaries package a try, but I get Latex errors if I use the symbols in math environments.

What would be the "state-of-the-art" solution to define my variables (which can be used also in math mode) at one global point? A list of symbols should be created automatically.

Comment: i may be misinterpreting something, but this seems like a compelling reason to use `\ensuremath`.

Comment: By *symbol directory*, do you mean *list of symbols*?

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Oh thx, yes this would work but I have read that \ensuremath comes with a lot of problems. Other solutions?

Comment: @Jubobs: yes, sorry I am not a native speaker...

Comment: if you're using `amsmath`, they you might try `\text{$...$}` as the expansion of your symbol code.  `\text` ensures the correct size in sub- and superscripts, but it's expected to be used within a math context, so if you use it in text (such as in an ordinary sentence, or even as the entry for your symbols list), you need to put it in `$...$'.  and if any of these symbols are supposed to be large operators (like `\sum`), this also won't automatically go into `\displaystyle` in a display equation.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As barbara mentioned, you can use `\ensuremath` like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{lengthtree}%
{%
  name={\ensuremath{L_t}},
  description={description here},
  sort={L}
}

\begin{document}

In line: \gls{lengthtree}. In math mode: 
\[
  \gls{lengthtree}
\]

\printglossary[title={List of Symbols}]

\end{document}
```

The arguments against `\ensuremath` come down to two main issues (see [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro)):

Firstly, you might end up with `$` inside the argument of `\ensuremath`. This won't occur in this example, as the argument of `\ensuremath` is being explicitly set to `L_t`.

Secondly, there is an issue of semantics. Following this line of argument, you should define the entry without `\ensuremath` and do `$\gls{lengthtest}$`, which is fine in the document text that you type, but this will cause a problem in the glossary where the style doesn't automatically shift to math mode when it comes to the entry name. Personally, I think `\ensuremath` is okay in this context, but for the purists who can't stand it, here's an alternative solution:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{lengthtree}%
{%
  name={$L_t$},
  text={L_t},
  description={description here},
  sort={L}
}

\begin{document}

In line: $\gls{lengthtree}$. In math mode: 
\[
  \gls{lengthtree}
\]

\printglossary[title={List of Symbols}]

\end{document}
```

Both the above examples produce:

[image: Image of document]

Comment: Of course I like best the second solution. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg I had a feeling you might `:-)`

Comment: Thx Nicola! I played with both solution and I prefer this solution. No problems so far and the package puts only symbols in the list which I have used.

Comment: Whenever I try and follow a latex solution such as this, I always get the error "glossary.sty could not be found", or similar for other packages. Why is this?

Comment: @NicolaTalbot Is it possible to make a separate file of glossary and use it in different source tex files?

Comment: @Arun Yes. You can input the file in the preamble using `\loadglsentries{` _filename_ `}`.

Answer (score 12):

I think you mean something like this, that defines the commands and makes a list at the same time.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\mysymbol[3]{%
\protected\gdef#1{#2}%
\item[$#2$]#3}

\begin{document}

\section*{List of symbols}

\begin{description}
\mysymbol{\zzz}{z_z^z}{Something about $Zzzzz$.}
\mysymbol{\Txxx}{Tx_{xx}}{The xx component of T.}
\mysymbol{\vvvv}{V_2}{$V$, the second.}
\mysymbol{\vvvvv}{V_3}{$V$, the third.}
\end{description}
\section{zzz}

\[ \zzz=\Txxx\]
where
\[\vvvv=3\]
and
\[\vvvvv=X\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: I prefer the solution from Nicola but your solution is also nice. Thanks for your help!!!

Comment: How to make hyperlink for these \mysymbol