# How do I automate writing list of symbols in my masters thesis?

Tags: symbols, automation

I'm using `documentclass{article}`. I have symbols, both in inline text and inside equations. How can I automate the process of listing them?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) What do you mean? Maybe you want a List of Symbols somewhere in your document?

Comment: thanks a lot karl :)

yeah so the idea is I have written down my thesis, with text and equations and now I need to make a List of Variables (I've called them symbols in my title) alongside Table of Contents, List of Figures and List of Tables.

I want to know if it's possible to automate this process i.e. I want a list of variables _without_ having to scan through the whole thesis and manual it down, instead pinning them all down in a list/table (other column for naming), possibly along with the code line number used in (to know of redundancies if any, which will be removed after cross-check)

Comment: Something like the [`nomencl`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nomencl) package?

Comment: sorry, I still have a doubt

http://ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf

in page 2, last two paragraphs and the next one on the next page. Can you explain?

Comment: edited in the last comment... taking me a while to adjust to the soft enter :)

Can you check it... thanks, I am using TexStudio to compile and build, where do I use makeindex and how?

ctan.imsc.res.in/macros/latex/contrib/nomencl/nomencl.pdf in page 2, last two paragraphs and the next one on the next page. Can you explain?

Comment: If your file is called `yourfile.tex` you have to run `makeindex -s nomencl.ist -t yourfile.nlg -o yourfile.nls yourfile.nlo` but I don't use TeXStudio so I don't know how to set it there. You can always run that command from the command line.

Comment: thanks it worked when I copied makeindex into the folder I was working in and ran it from command line in windows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to use the `glossaries` package. It is very customizable and provides you with a lot of control.
Furthermore, if you need to add a glossary, or a list of acronyms, you don't need other packages, because glossaries handles all this elements.

It has a specific `symbols` option to create a list of symbols.

With the command `\gls{}` (and its many variants, like `\glssymbol`, particulalry suited for thi case) you can display the symbol (and possible meaning) inline (the command has many variants).
Instead, with `\glsadd{}` you can make a symbol appear in the list of symbols even if you haven't used it explicitly.

In addition, [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137506/177) (provided by the very author of the package, btw) explains how to reference symbols within a mathematical environment.

Following this approach, I'm currently editing a set of documents with a list of acronyms, a list of symbols (to be used in math mode), and a glossary.
All with the same package, which is nice!

Addendum: don't be frightened by the large user manual. There is [glossariesbegin](http://mirror.unl.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.html) as a starter guide; but if you want to master your lists, better to face the complete user manual.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `nomencl` package for mathematical symbols. See [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/112884/how-to-achieve-nomenclature-entries-like-symbol-description-dimension-and-uni/112928#112928) as an example.

Also the `acronym` package is very powerful, [see this example](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86666/how-to-create-both-list-of-abbreviations-and-list-of-nomenclature-using-nomencl/87223#87223). Wich `acronym` you can do not only abbreviations but also math.