# Combining multiple math-mode glossary entries

Tags: math-mode, glossaries

I would like to combine 2 or more math mode glossary entries to form a complete expression in math-mode. Background is a separation of nomenclature and symbols.

I use expressions as in the second variant of this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/137506/101663

What I would like to get is shown in formula 1 of my MWE. What I get is shown in formula 2. What I suppose might happen is given in formula 3.

[image: result of MWE]

Ase one is not allowed (and it in fact doesn't work) to use gls-commands in the optional  parameter of a gls the approach given in the [manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.html#dx1-3048) does NOT help:

```
$\gls{Falpha}[^2]$
```

Is there any way to achieve my goal?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newglossary[fog]{formula}{foi}{foo}{Formula} 

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{mathpart1}{
    name=test, text=x_{ref},
    description=irrelevant, type=formula
} 

\newglossaryentry{mathpart2}{
    name=test2, text=^{abc},
    description=irrelevant2, type=formula
} 

\begin{document}
Desired output:
\[
    x_{ref}^{abc} = 0
\]

Achieved output with gls:
\[
    \gls{mathpart1}\gls{mathpart2} = 0
\]      

Similar behaviour:
\[
    {x_{ref}}^{abc} = 0
\]      
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\[
\gls{mathpart1}^{\gls{mathpart2}} = 0
\]`  works, of course, and just remove the `^` from the `abc` stuff. I think it is better not to use `^` in the gls - entry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the improved update below at the end.

I suggest to omit the superscript operator in the `gls` replacement text and use `\gls{foo}^{\gls{foobar}}` rather.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newglossary[fog]{formula}{foi}{foo}{Formula} 

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{mathpart1}{
    name=test, 
    text={\ensuremath{x_{ref}}},
    description=irrelevant, type=formula
} 

\newglossaryentry{mathpart2}{
    name=test2, 
    text={abc},
    description=irrelevant2, type=formula
} 



\begin{document}
Desired output:
\[
    x_{ref}^{abc} = 0
\]

Achieved output with gls:
\[
\gls{mathpart1}^{\gls{mathpart2}} = 0
\]      

Similar behaviour:
\[
    {x_{ref}}^{abc} = 0
\]      
\end{document}
```

**Update** -- According to the O.P. the `\glstextentry` is expandable, but `\gls` isn't. Use `\glstextentry` then.

Since `\gls` isn't expandable, `\gls{foo}\gls{foobar}` can't be expanded to something like `foo^{foobar}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\newglossary[fog]{formula}{foi}{foo}{Formula} 

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{mathpart1}{
    name=test, 
    text={\ensuremath{x_{ref}}},
    description=irrelevant, type=formula
} 

\newglossaryentry{mathpart2}{
    name=test2, 
    text={^{abc}},
    description=irrelevant2, type=formula
} 



\begin{document}
Desired output:
\[
    x_{ref}^{abc} = 0
\]

Achieved output with gls:
\[
\gls{mathpart1}\glsentrytext{mathpart2} = 0
\]      

Similar behaviour:
\[
    {x_{ref}}^{abc} = 0
\]      
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. While that works for this special case in the MWE I loose generality. When later on I decide to e.g. interchange ^ and _ between symbols and nomenclature I need to go through my large document and manually replace things.

Comment: @4reigner: Honestly, I don't know whether it's possible at all what you desire. I fear that `\gls`.. isn't really expandable

Comment: Thank you for the keyword "expandable". According to the doc $\glsentrytext$ is expandable. Replacing $\gls$ by $\glsentrytext$ in my MWE does the trick. Can I somehow accept your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: @4reigner: Well, I can change my answer to incorporate `\glsentrytext`, but comments can't be accepted.

Comment: @4reigner: I added your comment into the answer