# newglossaryentry: howto fill key with other keys for a subglossentry

Tags: glossaries

In a use-case more complex then the MWE I want to generate the symbol key of a glossary entry based on other keys (e.g. name & description). In the use-case the symbol a will be a math expression compossed of other custom keys b & c which are math expressions and need to be combined e.g. a:= b^c.

My approach in the MWE does work out for a first level entry, but fails for the second level entries. Please see the MWE output table column "Remarks" below for what I expect. I observed that the generated Symbol is allways that of the last defined child newglossaryentryin the script.

[image]

I would appreciate some help and suggestions for improvement.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}           

\newglossary[sog]{symbol}{soi}{soo}{Symbols}

\newglossarystyle{groupedsymbols}{%  
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%  
    {\begin{longtable}{llp{\glsdescwidth}}}%  
        {\bottomrule % booktabs
        \end{longtable}}%  
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
        \toprule % booktabs 
        \bfseries Category & %
        \bfseries Symbol & %
        \bfseries Remark %
        \\\endhead
        \midrule % booktabs
    }%  
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}% 
    %    
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        %\glsentryitem{##1} %
        \bfseries \glsentrydesc{##1} & & %
        \\
    }% 
    \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%  
         & \glsentrysymbol{##2} & \glsentrydesc{##2} %
        \\
    }% 
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\relax}
}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{group}{%
    type=symbol,
    name={testgroup},
    description={Categ. 1}
}

\newglossaryentry{groupentrytwo}{%
    type=symbol,
    parent=group,
    name={yabc},  
    description={Symbol WRONG ! should be: yabc},
    symbol={\glsentryname{\glslabel}}
} 

\newglossaryentry{groupentryone}{%
    type=symbol,
    parent=group,
    name={zabc},  
    description={Symbol is zabc correctly},
    symbol={\glsentryname{\glslabel}}
} 

\begin{document}
    \glsaddall[types={symbol}]
    \printglossary[type=symbol,style=groupedsymbols]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I suspect a grouping problem. If you use `\renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%  
      & \glsentrytext{##2} & \glsentrydesc{##2} %
      \\
    }%` it will work

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but that does not improve my somehow wrong approach to "construct a key from others in subentries" - which I need for my usecase.

Comment: Perhaps Nicola Talbot should answer this.

Comment: Obviously I did not get your point right away, until EngBIRD explained in greater detail. Thanks again for the proposed workaround. Please make a short answer out of your comment, so I can upvote it. Mind if I accept EngBIRD's answer as it is more complete?

Comment: No, just accept EngBIRD's answer. If you really want to upvote something, look for some other answers of mine ;-)  I am not really sure where the culprit is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe Christian Hupfer had the solution to your problem.  But if indeed it isn't what you were looking for perhaps you could clarify further.  I have expanded your MWE with the solution described above and I get the results that I infer to be expected.  Perhaps a more complex MWE is needed

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage[nomain,nonumberlist]{glossaries}           

\newglossary[sog]{symbol}{soi}{soo}{Symbols}

\newglossarystyle{groupedsymbols}{%  
    \renewenvironment{theglossary}%  
    {\begin{longtable}{llp{\glsdescwidth}}}%  
        {\bottomrule % booktabs
        \end{longtable}}%  
    \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{%
        \toprule % booktabs 
        \bfseries Category & %
        \bfseries Symbol & %
        \bfseries Remark %
        \\\endhead
        \midrule % booktabs
    }%  
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}% 
    %    
    \renewcommand*{\glossentry}[2]{%
        %\glsentryitem{##1} %
        \bfseries \glsentrydesc{##1} & & %
        \\
    }% 
    \renewcommand*{\subglossentry}[3]{%  
         & \glsentrytext{##2} & \glsentrydesc{##2} %
        \\
    }% 
    \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\relax}
}

\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{group}{%
    type=symbol,
    name={testgroup},
    description={Categ. 1}
}

\newglossaryentry{quadratic}{%
    type=symbol,
    name={testgrouptwo},
    description={quadratic formulas}
}

\newglossaryentry{groupentrytwo}{%
    type=symbol,
    parent=group,
    name={yabc},  
    description={Symbol WRONG ! should be: yabc  Not anymore.  This is what I expected.},
    symbol={\glsentryname{\glslabel}}
} 

\newglossaryentry{groupentryone}{%
    type=symbol,
    parent=group,
    name={zabc},  
    description={Symbol is zabc correctly as expected},
    symbol={\glsentryname{\glslabel}}
} 

\newglossaryentry{grouptwoentrytwo}{%
    type=symbol,
    parent=quadratic,
    name={$ax^2 + bx + c = 0$},  
    description={This is what I expect},
    symbol={\glsentryname{\glslabel}}
} 

\newglossaryentry{grouptwoentryone}{%
    type=symbol,
    parent=quadratic,
    name={$x = \frac{{ - b \pm \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac} }}{{2a}}$},  
    description={This is what I expect},
    symbol={\glsentryname{\glslabel}}
} 

\begin{document}
    \glsaddall[types={symbol}]
    \printglossary[type=symbol,style=groupedsymbols]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for adding more detail to the answer of Christian Hupfer. I got the point now. It seems to work with every key (pre or userdefined) except for symbol. Is that a bug or a feature?

Comment: @4reigner could you be more specific about what you mean about "except for symbol"?  If memory serves I have used many symbols (text annotations, Greek, and mathematical) in the past.  Give me a `newglossaryentry` or other MWE adjustment that doesn't work and I will do my best to investigate and help out.

Comment: apparently I was a bit to lax in my comment. I meant the symbol={..} approach in the initial MWE.

Comment: @4reigner When I add a `\glssymbol{grouptwoentryone}` call below the `\printglossary` call, I get the resulting math formula?  Is this what isn't working for you? Or is this not what you were expecting to get?  Perhaps you could be a bit more verbose in your comment, you have plenty of characters.

Comment: As discussed in http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/301090/combining-multiple-math-mode-glossary-entries I need a fully expandable glossaries-command. AFAIK from the discussion therein \glssymbol is not expandable and according to the initial MWE of this question here \glsentrysymbol does not work. As a solution has been found, I suggest to close this case.

Comment: @4reigner I am glad you found a solution to your problem.  I think I now understand the symbol instance you were describing.  Since my tex file didn't contain a `\glsentrysymbol` I couldn't find it and was getting lost.  For what it's worth, I also get the same result if I use `\glssymbol{##2}` inplace of `\glsentrytext{##2}` so keep that in mind if you ever have to move away from your definition of `symbol={\glsentryname{\glslabel}}`