# No show of list of symbols by using "glossaries" package

Tags: table-of-contents, symbols, glossaries

I am trying to produce a list of symbols for my thesis by using the latex code provided in this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137418/how-to-create-a-list-of-symbols-where-symbols-can-be-used-in-math-mode?newreg=ec3252e2a5d048a3ba7e60a62cf42f29)

I made the exactly copy but the part "List of Symbols" never shows up... Can someday help me to fix this?

Below you may find a minimum working example, and also a screenshot for the pdf file

```
\documentclass[english, reqno, 9pt]{amsart}
\usepackage{geometry}            % See geometry.pdf to learn the layout options. There are lots.
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,color}
\usepackage{mathrsfs,dsfont, comment,mathscinet}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{babel}






%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------%

\usepackage{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

\newglossaryentry{lengthtree}%
{%
  name={$L_t$},
  text={L_t},
  description={description here},
  sort={L}
}

\title{Test}


\setlength{\parindent}{0cm}
\begin{document}

In line: $\gls{lengthtree}$. In math mode: 
\[
  \gls{lengthtree}
\]

\printglossary[title={List of Symbols}]

\end{document}
```

[image]

So as you can see, there is no "List of symbols" section... Please advise!

Comment: have you run the `makeglossaries` script? Read the documentation for the `glossaries` package, around page 19. You can access that by typing in your terminal `texdoc glossaries`

Comment: @Moriambar ops... I certainly did not... Sorry, how may I run makeglossaries script? It is not like the 'bib' file I have for my references...

Comment: @Panda I answered. you simply type it in your command prompt. I also recommend you read the package documentation.  everything is there

Comment: @Moriambar I know how to do it now! It worked! Please, re-state your answer so I can accept it!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP just forgot to run `makeglossaries` and the problem was solved by suggestion in the comments.

Comment: @Panda done that

Comment: @TeXnician I understood. But I think this is not a trivial mistake... I know how to use bib file and some other tricks. But for glossaries... I never thought I need to use terminal in my laptop...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

In order for the glossaries to appear you have to:

1. Build the normal document using, e.g. LaTeX
2. Run the `makeglossaries` script on your file, by running `makeglossaries yourfilename` You have to type this in your terminal/command prompt window, in the same folder as your compiled file
3. Run again LaTeX

This way LaTeX will be able to produce the requested glossary, e.g.

[image]

For any further details please read the `glossaries` package documentation, especially the introductory section around page 19. (`texdoc glossaries` from command line should produce that)

Comment: Sorry. I am a bit new to latex. By terminal you mean the terminal for my laptop OS or the console (yellow box) for latex? I am using TeXShop.

Comment: Your os terminal. In mac is just called terminal