# How to add separate "list of symbols" when "list of abbreviations" is already produced by glossaries?

Tags: glossaries, front-matter

### My University's dissertation class uses `glossaries` to produces a "LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS". I want to use it to produce a second list, a simple "LIST OF SYMBOLS".

### Can this be done with `glossaries`? How to do it?

---

Here is how my current jumble of latex files uses glossaries. First, the `.cls` file includes a `\RequirePackage[nonumberlist, nopostdot]{glossaries}`. Then, I add some lines to the preamble of the `main.tex` file:

```
\newacronym{fpga}{FPGA}{Field-Programmable Gate Array}
\newacronym{lqr}{LQR}{Linear Quadratic Regulator}
```

Then when I use `\gls{fpga}` and `\gls{lqr}` in my document, it does a fantastic job of inserting text and generating a list of abbreviations.

After digging through my jumble of files, I found that `main.tex` calls `lists.tex` which has the following code:

```
\phantomsection
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
\begingroup
\pagestyle{loastyle}
\makeatletter
\let\ps@plain\ps@normal
\makeatother
\vspace{0.07in}
\printglossary[style=grizz_glossary]
\addtolength{\textheight}{0.85in}
\newpage
\endgroup
```

It then goes back to `.cls` with this:

```
% Glossary
\newglossarystyle{grizz_glossary}{
\renewcommand{\glossaryname}{\vspace*{0.2in}LIST OF ABBREVIATIONS}
 % put the glossary in the tabular environment:  
 \renewenvironment{theglossary}%  
   {\noindent\begin{longtable}{p{1.13in}p{4.37in}}}{\end{longtable}}%  
 % have nothing after \begin{theglossary}:  
 \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%  
 % have nothing between glossary groups:  
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{}%  
 \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{}%  

 \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{  
        \glstarget{##1}{##2}\hfill & ##3\hfill \vspace{12pt}\\
 }   
}
```

I also need to run some perl, with the command `makeglossaries main` to get this to generate right.

What do I need to change? The documentation for `glossaries` is super involved, and some hints would help.

Related questions:

[This one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/348640/67392) seems related but is very complicated, and requires hyperlinks.

[Another One](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/137418/how-to-create-a-list-of-symbols-where-symbols-can-be-used-in-math-mode) is close, but different enough that I don't know what to do.

Edit:

As suggested by @EladDen in the comments, [How to combine Acronym and Glossary](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8946/how-to-combine-acronym-and-glossary) provides some valuable clues, but it is far too complicated. A good answer there is integrated and produces two lists from one set of data. I want to produce two separate lists from two separate data sets.

Spectifically, the "List of Abbreviations" will look like this:

FPGA    Field-Programmable Gate Array
LQR     Linear Quadratic Regulator

Whereas the "list of symbols" will look like this:

*m*       Mass
*F*       Force
*a*       Acceleration

Again, I want to emphasize that they will come from a completely difference dataset. Perhaps there is a command `\newsymbol` in glossaries?

Comment: Check this answer out https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/8951/90297

Comment: @EladDen Edited to address your comments.

Comment: I believe you're looking for `\newglossaryentry`. I also recommend you read the glossaries beginners user manual.

Comment: That last comment was the answer in short. The long answer is that `\newglossaryentry` is the general declaration. If not stated otherwise in the type field the package would treat this definition as a symbol and `\newacronym` as an acronym. You COULD if you wanted to define an acronym through the `\newglossaryentry` by using the `type` field, for more information, I would recommend reading the full user manual.