# How to write partial differential equation (Ex. dQ/dt=ds/dt) with real partial derivative signs?

Tags: equations

I would like to make a partial differential equation by using the following notation:

dQ/dt

(without / but with a real numerator and denomenator). Earlier today I got help from this page on how to `u_t`, but now I also have to write it like `dQ/dt`. I understand how it can be done by using dollarsigns and fractions, but is it possible to do it using

```
\begin{equation}
....
\end{equation}
```

so that it can be on separate lines and using math-style?

Comment: See also [`cool`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cool): "The pack­age (COn­tent Ori­ented LaTeX) gives LaTeX the power to re­tain mathemat­i­cal mean­ing of its ex­pres­sions in ad­di­tion to the typsetting in­struc­tions; es­sen­tially sep­a­rat­ing style from the con­tent of the math."

Answer (score 211, accepted):

You said partial differential equation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial s}{\partial t}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

now using `physics` package, extra goodies (bonus):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{physics}
\begin{document}
\[
\dv{Q}{t} = \dv{s}{t}  \quad
\dv[n]{Q}{t} = \dv[n]{s}{t}  \quad
\pdv{Q}{t} = \pdv{s}{t}  \quad
\pdv[n]{Q}{t} = \pdv[n]{s}{t}  \quad
\pdv{Q}{x}{t} = \pdv{s}{x}{t}  \quad
\]
\[
\fdv{F}{g}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for both answers! Both of them worked perfect.

Comment: I also tried the second option you gave, but when I had written \usepackage{physics} at the top of the document, I got this as an output: ! LaTeX Error: File `physics.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name:

Comment: What should I enter as file name?

Comment: @David It means you don't have `physics` package installed. Please install it.

Comment: Note that we can italicize the d's using `\usepackage[italicdiff]{physics}`.

Comment: Thank you, I never know there was a physics package .

Answer (score 18):

Another possibility to write classic derivates or partial derivates I suggest (IMHO), actually, to use [derivative](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/derivative/derivative.pdf) package.
For my humble opinion it is very good and last release is ****2024/02/08, v1.4**
**. Here there are some examples take, some, from the guide:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{derivative}
\begin{document}
\[
\pdv{f}{x}, \quad \odv{Q}{t}=\odv{s}{t}, \quad \pdv{f}{x,y}, \quad 
\derivset{\odv}[switch-*=false] \odv{y}{x}, \quad \odv[n]{y}{x}, \quad
\derivset{\odv}[misc-add-delims=fun] \odv*{\odv{y}{x}}{x}, \quad 
\derivset{\pdv}[sort-method={sign,symbol,abs}] \pdv[c+kn,-b+2a]{f}{x,y}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Just fully agree IMHO with your HO: this package is very good. It is easy to use and has powerful options. +1

Comment: @loved.by.Jesus I am help that you have appreciated my answer. + 1 also for you and other.

Comment: What is the mnemonic for `odv` and `pdv`? I would guess "Ordinary Derivative..." and "Partial Derivative..." but what is the `v` standing for?

Comment: @lucidbrot I got the naming scheme from another package, I think it was physics, but at least in my package dv stands for "DeriVative" or for short "DeriV". The latter is also the prefix for the internal package commands.

Answer (score 7):

I now recommend using the [cool](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cool) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cool}
\begin{document}
Text:
\[
    \pderiv{u}{t}=\pderiv[2]{u}{x}
\]
More text.
\end{document}
```

I used to recommend defining a command to make a short form:

```
\documentclass{article}
% Partial derivative
\newcommand*{\pd}[3][]{\ensuremath{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3}}}
\begin{document}
Text:
\[
    \pd{u}{t}=\pd[2]{u}{x^2}
\]
More text.
\end{document}
```

[image: what it looks like]

Comment: There is rarely a good use of `\ensuremath`. While there's nothing really _wrong_ with it, it removes semantic meaning without adding much of anything else. See [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro)

Comment: You do not have to make that square in denominator by hand... you can formulate it in this way:
\newcommand{\pdv}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1}#2}{\partial {#3}^{#1}}}

Comment: @JozefJanočko Note that `\partial^{}u` (the default in your solution) will give more spacing compared to `\partial u`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
```

Comment: This doesn't add anything more than isn't already covered in the other answer(s).

Answer (score 2):

All good answers. I would just like to mention that if your are somewhat new to LaTeX, you should get used to using \newcommand and \renewcommand. For example:

% __________ Differentials __________

% Single

```
  \newcommand{\diff}{d}           % If you want an upright `d', change it here
  \newcommand{\p}[1]{\partial#1}
  \newcommand{\q}[1]{\delta#1}    % Kronecker Delta/Variation Symbol
```

% Nth Differentials:

```
  \newcommand{\dN}[2]{\diff^{#1}{#2}}   % Numerator type
  \newcommand{\pN}[2]{\partial^{#1}{#2}}
  \newcommand{\qN}[2]{\delta^{#1}{#2}}
```

% Nth Powers of Differentials

```
  \newcommand{\dD}[2]{\diff{#2}^{#1}}   % Denominator type
  \newcommand{\pD}[2]{\p{#2}^{#1}}
  \newcommand{\qD}[2]{\delta{#2}^{#1}}
  \newcommand{\pd}[1]{\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{#1}}}
  \newcommand{\pdd}[2]{\dfrac{\partial{#1}}{\partial{#2}}}
```

% __________ Derivatives __________

% 1st derivative:

```
\newcommand{\dod}[2]{\dfrac{\diff{#1}}{\diff{#2}}}  % 'differential over differential'
\newcommand{\pop}[2]{\dfrac{\p#1}{\p#2}}            % 'partial over partial'
\newcommand{\lpop}[2]{\p#1/\p#2}            % A 'layed down' version
\newcommand{\qoq}[2]{\dfrac{\q#1}{\q#2}}
```

% Nth derivative:

```
\newcommand{\dodN}[3]{\dfrac{\dN{#1}{#2}}{\dD{#1}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\popN}[3]{\dfrac{\pN{#1}{#2}}{\pD{#1}{#3}}}
\newcommand{\lpopN}[3]{\pN{#1}{#2}/\pD{#1}{#3}}  % Layed version of \pop
\newcommand{\qoqN}[3]{\dfrac{\qN{#1}{#2}}{\qD{#1}{#3}}}
```

% Mixed

```
\newcommand{\dodMixed}[3]{\dfrac{\dN{2}{#1}}{\diff{#2}\diff{#3}}}
\newcommand{\popMixed}[3]{\dfrac{\pN{2}{#1}}{\p{#2}\p{#3}}}
\newcommand{\lpopMixed}[3]{\pN{2}{#1}/\p{#2}\p{#3}}
\newcommand{\qoqMixed}[3]{\dfrac{\qN{2}{#1}}{\q{#2}\q{#3}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use [`hep-math`](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/hep-math/hep-math-documentation.pdf) package (2023/07/01). Here a little **tex.code** compilable.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{hep-math}
\renewcommand{\diffsymbol}{\mathrm d} % optional upright d
\begin{document}

\[\dv[f]x,\quad, \dv*[f]x^n,\quad, \dv[f]x*^n,\quad, \dv*[f]x*^n\]
\[\dv xf,\quad, \dv*xf,\quad, \dv x*f,\quad, \dv*x*f\]
\[\pdv[f]h,\quad, \pdv[f]y[x],\quad, \pdv[f]x^5,\quad, \pdv[f]x^3[y^2]\]
\[\pdv[f]x^2[y]^3, \pdv[f]x[y]^3, \pdv x[y]f\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 for bringing up a package I didn't know but I wouldn't recommend it...