# Redefining math symbols like \eta (with ensuremath)

Tags: math-mode, macros

An easy one: I would like to define a shortcut so that I can write `\eta` without having to enclose it in `$\eta$`.

However, the naive approach will not work:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\pt}{\ensuremath{p_T}}
% \renewcommand{\eta}{\ensuremath{\eta}} % hangs if I do it like this

\begin{document}

I have $\pt = x$, $\eta = y$. 

Just like \pt, I can also refer to %\eta.
--- no I can't.

\end{document}
```

It seems this approach results in an endless loop. What is the best way around this?

Comment: What's the purpose? I find no advantage whatsoever.

Comment: Of course it does, since it tries to use `eta`

Comment: I'm saving two key strokes.

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig And making your input more confusing.

Comment: The macroname `\pt` is not really recommendable, as it is misleading and could be confused with the TeX dimension `pt`

Comment: Thanks for the hint about `\pt`. However, it did a good job for me so far... (I never use / need the TeX dimension but I need to refer to the transverse momentum *a lot*.)

Comment: I agree with egreg, `$\pt$` gives a much clearer markup. Most editors will also highlight it. Also you will have to remember `blah blah \pt{} blah blah` so that it does not eat a space. So those saved `$` will come and bite you in the end.

Comment: Nope: I always use `xspace` for things like `\pt` (I didn't include it in the minimal example, however). So it would be `blah \pt blah`. I appreciate all the well-intentioned comments, but you may trust me: It does work very well for me :) (`\pt` is also highlighted by the way.)

Comment: @fuenfundachtzig, then look back though the archives to find what many people think about `xparse`, there are situations where `\xparse` does it wrong.... (don't remember them from the top of may head)

Comment: @daleif Are you talking about `xparse` or `xspace`?

Comment: @sebhofer, typo, `\xspace`, my bad

Comment: @daleif The discussion you are probably thinking of is [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/18321) btw.

Comment: See [When not to use `\ensuremath` for math macro](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/) for some hints about the problem. If you try `\pt+\eta` you'll get spacing completely wrong, unless you add `$` around the expression. And `\pt-\eta` in text mode would be really outrageous.

Comment: Yes, there are corner cases in which `\xspace` gets the spacing wrong. Still, I found it to be a tremendous help, and those cases in which it fails cannot be that numerous because I cannot come up with one from the top of my head.

Answer (score 4):

Regardless whether it's useful or not, as a shortcut without `$...$` it's possible to redefine `\eta`, but it's necessary to store the meaning of `\eta` before (making a copy) using `\let`.

My statements are of general nature, I do not really recommend to use `\eta` in this way.

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcommand{\pt}{\ensuremath{p_T}}
\let\etaorig\eta%
\renewcommand{\eta}{\ensuremath{\etaorig}} % hangs if I do it like this

\begin{document}

I have $\pt = x$, $\eta = y$. 

Just like \pt, I can also refer to \eta.
--- Yes I can!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach which doesn't allocate the new name `\etaorig`:

```
\edef\eta{\noexpand\ensuremath{\mathchar\the\eta\space}}
```

Comment: What if `\eta` happens to not be defined with `\mathchardef`? I *know* this is usually the case, but why assuming it?

Comment: @egreg I assumed this because I suppose that user will need to redefine `\alpha`, `\beta` etc. These `\mathcharedef` charcters can be redefined without allocating `\alphaorig`, `\betaorig`, ..., `\omegaorig`.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. What if `\eta` is ***not*** defined with `\mathchardef`, but some package, for its own purpose, has changed the usual definition into something else? Say for getting a different symbol in some non math alphabet. Unlikely, but why making assumptions when it's possible to avoid them?