# Math command that works in text and math mode

Tags: math-mode, best-practices

The command

```
\newcommand{\rsim}{\text{$\overset{r}{\sim}$ }}
```

works in text and math mode. That said, the workaround looks somewhat ugly, as text mode and math mode are summoned for a single character.

I'll use that symbol a lot in a long document, and I fear compiling will take longer because of the workaround.

Is there a better way to define a math-and-text command?

Comment: What's the problem in writing `$\rsim$`? A math symbol is never text. Note that your definition always produces a space that's generally not wanted. So you should remove the trailing space and type `\rsim{}` in text, with the same number of keystrokes. I can't see any advantage.

Comment: I'll use it in text and math mode, so not having to use dollar signs makes writing a bit faster.

Comment: It's *wrong* to begin with. But if you really have hundreds of appearances, do `\newcommand{\rsim}{\ensuremath{\overset{r}{\sim}}\xspace}`. But be advised that this might have unwanted consequences in some circumstances; always better than a wrong space, of course. Add `\usepackage{xspace}`. Also taking a one-way road from the wrong side can be faster than doing a longer route, but…

Comment: What's wrong in making that command?

Comment: Have you ever compared the space? Try your definition with `\rsim,` and you'll see.

Comment: I think you should have thousands of `\rsim`s in your document to see some noticeable compiling delay

Comment: Is spacing the only wrong thing in there? That incomplete phrase made me think it was much worse.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You tagged the question as [best-practices](/questions/tagged/best-practices), so first I'll tell you what's the best practice:

> always treat math symbols as math

So the definition should be

```
\newcommand{\rsim}{\overset{r}{\sim}}
```

to be used like

```
We will use the symbol $\rsim$ to denote a very useful
equivalence relation, namely $a\rsim b$ if and only if
$a$ and $b$ are equally handsome.
```

If you want to break the “law” that math symbols are to be always regarded as such, then you can do

```
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\rsim}{\ensuremath{\overset{r}{\sim}}\xspace}
```

and the text above can become

```
We will use the symbol \rsim to denote a very useful
equivalence relation, namely $a\rsim b$ if and only if
$a$ and $b$ are equally handsome.
```

What's the gain? None at all. You even lose syntax coloring.

See [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro)

Comment: I used the original `\rsim` definition in math mode and funny things went on with spaces. I am convinced now.