# Writing a macro that works both in math formula and text

Tags: macros

Can I write one macro that works conditioned on it is in math formula or not?

For example, assume I have an algorithm named "alg1"  and I want the name to be in `\mathsf` so normally I define two macros as follows: 1) `\def\a{\mathsf{alg1}}` and 2) `\def\b{$\mathsf{alg1}$}`. One is for when I want to use "alg1" name in a math formula and the other one is for when I want to use the name in a text environment.

So is there a way to write one macro for both applications?

Comment: Don't. You gain nothing and lose much.

Comment: @egreg
 sorry , could you explain why it is a bad practice ?

Comment: I went through similar thinking when I started with LaTeX as well: [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/4301)

Comment: See, besides the link posted by Peter, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35877/4427 https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/444671/4427 https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/289064/4427

Comment: People recommand `\ensuremath`. I don't. If in text-mode consecutive "`\ensuremath`-commands" occur, this will not be treated as a single math-formula but will be treated as different adjoining formulas. This will not necessarily look good. You need to have TeX enter math-mode, then to process subsequent  "`\ensuremath`-commands", then to leave math-mode. But this way `\ensuremath` is obsolete.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `\ensuremath`:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}

\newcommand{\HT}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{H}} }
\begin{document}
See \HT and $\HT$
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum:**
You may be interested in the following version in which `\HT` enabled by `xspace` package:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\HT}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{H}}\xspace}

\begin{document}
See \HT and $\HT$, and when at of the sentence is \HT.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice. It works :). thanks so much.

Comment: Why the wrong braces? `\ensuremath{\mathcal{H}}` would be the syntax.

Comment: @egreg, you are right.  Corrected now.

Comment: @mike, see addendum to answer.

Comment: @Zarko What are the advantages of second solution (using xspace) over the first solution?

Comment: @mike, compare results of compiling sentence: `See \HT and $\HT$, and when at of the sentence is \HT.`  with first and second  definition of `\HT`. You should observe differences in space after `\HT`.

Comment: @Zarko Ok, Thanks.