# How to define your own shorter command in place of the default longer command?

Tags: math-mode, macros

I would like to not type `$\mathbf{\hat{x}}$` every time I want a bold `x` with a hat over it. I've used \def successfully for other things, but with this I am not sure how to properly use `\def` or `\newcommand` in order for me to just type `\bhat{x}` and have it bold the input letter (whatever that may be - could be an `x`, `y`, `z`, etc.).

I've tried this, but it does not work:

```
\newcommand{\mathbf{\hat{}}}[1][1]{\bhat} % or...
\def\bhat{{\mbox{$\hat \mathbf{}$}}}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hope this is what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\bhat[1]{\ensuremath{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
some text $\bhat{x}$ or \bhat{y} 
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Why not using `\ensuremath` if the new command is used in a mathematical environment `$...\bhat{x}...$` ?

I would suggest `\newcommand{\bhat}[1]{\ensuremath{\hat{\mathbf{#1}}}}`, then you do not need to put the `\bhat` command between dollars.

Comment: Relevant: [When not to use `\ensuremath` for math macro?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/5764)

Comment: @JérômeDequeker:  Edited to add \ensuremath

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for the link. I think in this kind of usage, the argument in the `\bhat` command is only a letter, but thank you to notice we should not put dollars in the arguments.

Comment: Has the hat to be bold too ? If Yes, @AmbikaVanchinathan knows what to edit in the answer.

Comment: @magnetar: Please swap the hat and mathbf in the definition, if the hat needs to be in bold too.

Comment: @AmbikaVanchinathan Swapping the commands will not make the hat bold. You shouldn't have added `\ensuremath`.

Comment: This worked beautifully, thanks! I tested this within and out of math environments, as well as in-line with regular text with and without dollar signs around it and it all works.

Answer (score 0):

\def \hope#1{\bf{\hat{#1}}}
       \begin{document}
     This is $\hope{V}$
     \end{document}% this works for me. You can use any term inside curly      bracket where V is added. It gives proper result.

Comment: The command `\bf` has been deprecated more than 20 years ago. And no, this doesn't give proper results, because `$\hope{V}W$` will make bold also the `W`.