# How one can use a `\newcommand` for some formulas?

Tags: macros

I have some formula such as `\mathbf{x}_{j_{1}}, \mathbf{x}_{j_{2}},...,` and `\mathbf{x}_{j_{k}}`. How can I  define one `\newcommand` for these formulas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you intend a command where to change only the variable part...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\newcommand{\myf}[1]{\mathbf{x}_{j_{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\[
\myf{1}, \myf{2}, \dots, \myf{k}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You might want to add an `\ensuremath`.

Comment: @Skillmon See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/101651

Comment: @CarLaTeX thanks, never considered these (though I'm not fully convinced yet).

Comment: @Skillmon Wait, I'll ask for egreg's advice in chat!

Comment: @CarLaTeX he'll say 'DON'T!'. I think it depends on the usage of FahimB.

Comment: @Skillmon Why you aren't convinced, then? Please visit our chat and let's continue the discussion there!

Comment: @Skillmon Of course I say *don't*! ;-) You just gain in obfuscation if you allow `\myf{1}` to be used without segregating it in a math formula, even if it just consists in `$\myf{1}$`.