# Nested \newcommand's in Latex

Tags: macros

I find myself needing to define many different macros relating to variables, spaces, etc. to help define consistent font choices (\mathsf,\mathcal, normal, etc).  These all essentially look like:

`\newcommand{\P}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{P}}\xspace}`

which lets `\P` be used in text/math mode, not eat spaces after it, etc. All essentially what I want out of notation definition.

I've abstracted this command system to the following constructor:

`\newcommand{\makespace}[2]{\newcommand{#1}{\ensuremath{\mathcal{#2}}\xspace}}`

With this macro, I'll have `\makespace{\P}{P}` produce the first macro I wrote, which makes all of my macro definitions more consistent/readible.  I could just leave it at this, but I'll need to define multiple constructors - as an example, something like:

`\newcommand{\makeconstant}[2]{\newcommand{#1}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{#2}}\xspace}}`

(where `\mathcal` was replaced with `\mathsf`) would also need to be defined.  So, it seems like making a constructor of constructors would be prudent, which I'd imagine would look like:

`\newcommand{\makeconstructor}[2]{\newcommand{#1}[2]{\newcommand{#1'}{\ensuremath{#2{#2'}}\xspace}}}`

Here's my issue - I want this two parameter macro to return a two parameter macro.  How can I differentiate between #1 and #1' (which I'm sure is the incorrect notation)?  What's the correct way to "keep the paramters separate" when defining a higher-order function such as this?

Comment: Where do I start? I mean, pardon my sincere tone, but you're actually doing three things that should not be done. **(1)** [Use `\xspace`.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/86620) **(2)** [Use `\ensuremath` improperly.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35877) **(3)** Define or re-define one-letter macros for math symbols instead of using more descriptive names. Note that your code would not compile with the error `! LaTeX Error: Command \P already defined. Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.`

Comment: If you want to reference an argument of an inner command, use `##1`, if you want to reference an argument of a command inside a command inside a command, use `####1` if you want to ... use `########1` etc. Also, do not redefine one-letter commands, they are reserved. What you do here, is redifining the macro `newcommand`. This is at least strange.

Comment: @yo' I appreciate the criticism.  The \P example actually has name `\player` in usage, for whatever reason I decided against including that here. As for not using `xspace`, if I have issues with it eating spaces should I try throwing an `{}` on the end of whatever is causing issues, and then posting here if that doesn't work?  It was introduced to me by one of my coauthors who's quite a bit more senior than me.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Am I redefining \newcommand, or defining an alternative usage/a `template` for it?  I'm attempting to do the second, but if this would break \newcommand inadvertently that makes this all not worth it.

Comment: @Mark Your use of both `xspace` and `ensuremath` is linked. Why not `$\player$`?

Comment: @Mark you use a command that calls `\newcommand`, which can be considered unsafe.

Comment: @yo' I agree that `\xspace` in this example is undesirable.  However, it can be very useful.  For instance, in `todonotes` `\todo` gobbles up the space after it.  It's innocuous to redefine `\todo` to include an `\xspace` since todo notes won't appear in the final manuscript, anyway.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I don't think this use case is unsafe: it's no different than the kind of macro we would use in a package to create an internal macro from a user-facing macro.  These are clearly intended to be used in the preamble to set up shorthands.

Comment: @yo' I was unaware that `\xspace` and `\ensuremath` were considered bad form, and just from a readability of code standpoint preferred `\player`.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman the intent with defining these is that it makes aesthetic decisions (regarding which of `\mathsf`, `\mathcal`, etc to wrap things in) more fluid/easily implemented, and making the section of the preamble where all this notation is actually defined slightly less verbose.

Comment: @Mark i will post an answer then based on your last comment.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman your comments here are incorrect sorry, the suggested definition does not redefine `\newcommand` (and single letter names are not in general reserved)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't mean it redefines 'newcommand', but it does the same as it.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman I think you misunderstood the intended use. See my example which demonstrates the working version.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle maybe i misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Abstract also the formatting command

```
\newcommand{\newdescriptor}[3]{\newcommand{#1}{#2{#3}}}
```

Then

```
\newdescriptor{\sP}{\mathbf}{P}
```

will do

```
\newcommand{\sP}{\mathbf{P}}
```

Nowhere I see any improvement over the direct definition *unless* you do a further abstraction step:

```
\newcommand{\whatever}[1]{\mathbf{#1}}
\newcommand{\constant}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}

\newcommand{\newdescriptor}[3]{\newcommand{#1}{#2{#3}}}

\newdescriptor{\sP}{\whatever}{P}
\newdescriptor{\cs}{\constant}{S}
```

Add `\ensuremath` and `\xspace` if you really want. I will never be convinced that typing

```
The constant \cS is nice
```

is better than typing

```
The constant \(\cS\) is nice
```

To be honest, I find the second way the only good one (on par with `$\cS$`).

Comment: Are `\(\cS\)` and `$\cS$` interpreted equivalently by Latex?

Comment: @Mark Yes, but the former does a further check.

Comment: @Mark Not completely equivalently, but to day, usage of `$...$` is considered fine.

Comment: For other people interested in the "further check" [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/510/are-and-preferable-to-dollar-signs-for-math-mode) might be a good starting point.

Answer (score 9):

In the replacement text of a definition `#2` is replaced by the second argument, `#1` is replaced by the first argument, and `##` is replaced by `#` so

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\makeconstructor}[2]{%
\newcommand{#1}[2]{\newcommand{##1}{\ensuremath{#2{##2}}\xspace}}}

\makeconstructor\makespace\mathcal
\makeconstructor\makewidget\mathsf

\makespace\SP{P}
\makespace\SQ{Q}
\makewidget\WP{P}
\makewidget\WQ{Q}


\begin{document}

$\SP<\SQ<\WP<\WQ$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautifully concise!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes it's the intended syntax of the OP, I just corrected `#1'` to `##1`.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, the main problem can be solved with defining new "style" of typesetting. To change everything with one click, we can now edit one line in preamble.

```
\documentclass{article}
    
\newcommand{\mystyle}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
\newcommand{\player}{\mystyle{P}}

\begin{document}
    
    \noindent
    Here is calligrafic font.
    \[
    \player
    \]
    Oops, seems like now I want all letters to be Sans Serif.
    
    \renewcommand{\mystyle}[1]{\mathsf{#1}}
    \[
    \player
    \]
    
\end{document}
```

Here is the result.
[image]

Comment: And of course you should not be using `$$... $$`  in latex