# \mathrm inside align not working

Tags: align, chemistry

I am trying to make a document and using `\mathrm` inside an `align*` environment. But it doesn't works, any help?

Here I paste a **ME** (it doesn't work but it is complete)

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[headheight=18pt,a4paper, width=150mm, top=25mm, bottom=25mm, bindingoffset=6mm, headsep=18pt]{geometry}
%aca utilizo la geometría de la hoja 
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}
%interprete de idioma castellano
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\begin{align*}
{\mathrm{pH}}={\mathrm{p}}K_{{\mathrm{a}}}+\log _{{10}}\left({\frac  {[{\mathrm{A}}]}{[{\mathrm{HA}^{+}}]}}\right)\\
\intertext{Para un pKa de 14.0, correspondiende a la guanidina sustituida}
{\mathrm{\num2.5e-7}}=\frac{[{\mathrm{A}}]}{[{\mathrm{HA}^{+}}]}\\
\intertext{Para 9.5 del cis dihidro dihidroxi imidazol}
{\mathrm{\num0.01}}=\frac{[{\mathrm{A}}]}{[{\mathrm{HA}^{+}}]}\\
\intertext{Para 6.2 del trans dihidro dihidroxi imidazol}
{\mathrm{\num15.85}}=\frac{[{\mathrm{A}}]}{[{\mathrm{HA}^{+}}]}\\
\end{align*}
```

Comment: There are three things missing here: 1) a `document` environment. 2) the `amsmath` package (which defines `align`). 2) the `siunitx` package (which defines `\num`)

Comment: At the least you have too many braces.

Comment: yeah as I am almost a beginner with latex I make all kind of errors.   @egreg

Comment: @TorbjørnT. fixed with advice numer 2). Thanks! if you want answer or I can remove the question.

Comment: Why are all those variables upright anyway? (just asking)

Comment: what variables? @daleif

Comment: @daleif `H^+`, `HA` and `A^-` is chemical content (`A` being an arbitrary acid) which is typically typeset upright. I'd use the `chemformula` and `chemmacros` packages for typesetting content like this.

Comment: @clemens I am using those packages but in that expression it was more or less the same..I suppose. And do they work inside align?

Comment: @HernanMiraola as the accepted answer shows: yes, `chemformula`'s `\ch` works inside math. Also `chemmacros`' `\pH` and `\pKa` do work inside math…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you need `align` and `\intertext`: the equations are mostly independent from each other.

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[
  a4paper,
  width=150mm,
  top=25mm,
  bottom=25mm,
  heightrounded,
  bindingoffset=6mm,
  headheight=18pt,
  headsep=18pt,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %relacionado al input
\usepackage[spanish,es-noquoting]{babel}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\newcommand{\pH}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{pH}}}
\newcommand{\pKa}{\ensuremath{\mathrm{p}K_{\mathrm{a}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\pH = \pKa + \log_{10}\left(\frac{[\ch{A}]}{[\ch{HA+}]}\right)
\end{equation*}
Para un \pKa{} de \num{14.0}, correspondiende a la guanidina sustituida
\begin{equation*}
\num{2.5e-7}=\frac{[\ch{A}]}{[\ch{HA+}]}
\end{equation*}
Para \num{9.5} del cis dihidro dihidroxi imidazol
\begin{equation*}
\num{0.01}=\frac{[\ch{A}]}{[\ch{HA+}]}
\end{equation*}
Para \num{6.2} del trans dihidro dihidroxi imidazol
\begin{equation*}
\num{15.85}=\frac{[\ch{A}]}{[\ch{HA+}]}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Note how `\ch` makes it easier to input chemical formulas; I added definitions for `\pH` and `\pKa` so as to further simplify the input.

You were using `\num` wrongly.

[image]

### Side note

Some might be surprised by my usage of `\ensuremath` in `\pH` and `\pKa` in comparison with my answer to [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro)

Why do I deem it right here? The reason is simple. Neither macro is for mathematical text: the two symbols usually appear in text, but they *can* also appear in math. Using `\ensuremath` in the definition ensures uniform printing of these *symbols* that shouldn't change format depending on current conditions. Requiring `$\pH$` if the symbol is in text would be unreasonable, because it is not math to begin with.