# Use \newcommand with variable math environment

Tags: math-mode, environments

I'm writing a text where the variable I_{a,b,c}^{d,e,f} occurs a lot. It occurs as well in plain text as in mathematical environments. I would like ONE command, that can be used in both cases, something like

```
\newcommand{\Ioften}{$I_{a,b,c}^{d,e,f}$}
```

However this will only work, when I use it in plain text, not in the mathematical environment. That is I could use it now \Ioften, but not in the equation `$3\cdot \Ioften$`

Comment: If you _must_, you can use `\ensuremath`. Personally, I'd just define `\Ioften` without `$` and insert them manually when writing inline math.

Comment: @campa can you explain why it's not a good idea to use `\ensuremath`? To me this looks like a good idea

Comment: In some (rare) circumstances it could break down. And the idea of markup is to clearly separate text and math contents. [This question (and answers therein)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/82917) discuss esthe issue a little bit. This being said, it is not bad per se: if it makes your life easier, use it.