# math expression inside math expression

Tags: macros

Let us assume the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\pt}{$p_{T}$}
\begin{document}

We analyse all cases of the transverse momentum \pt. First, let us 
assume that $p_{T} \leq 50 \text{GeV}$.

\end{document}
```

The result is

[image]

It is inviting to use the command `\pt` in the second mathematical expression and write it like that

```
$\pt \leq 50 \text{GeV}$
```

In case I do it, I get the error

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.6 ...omentum \pt. First, let us assume that $\pt
                                                   \leq 50 \text{GeV}$.
```

Suggestions?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem? Maybe you're using the wrong case of the command? (`\pt` is different of `\pT`)

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I clarified and corrected the question.

Comment: See [When not to use `\ensuremath` for math macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\pt}{\ensuremath{p_T^{}}\xspace}
\begin{document}

We analyse all cases of the transverse momentum \pt. First, let us
assume that $\pt \leq 50 \text{GeV}$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

`xspace` ensure correct spacing after use of `\pt`.

Comment: `\xspace`, I see, is indeed important. But the use of `^{}` I don't understand.

Comment: @Viesturs, compare $p_T$ and $p_T^{}$, and observe difference. i prefer the second result :-)

Comment: It seems that `T` is lower if `^{}` is used.

Comment: @Viesturs, yes. `^{}` push subscripts down and with this prepare more space for superscripts (which in this case is not used). similar effect you can obtain with use of package `subdepth`.

Comment: I consider `\xspace` as important therefore I shift "Accepted answer" to this answer.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the `\pt` macro contains `$...$`. The solution is to either use `\ensuremath`, so that the `$...$` are added when needed,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\pt}{\ensuremath{p_{T}}}
\begin{document}

We analyse all cases of the transverse momentum \pt. First, let us
assume that $p_{T} \leq 50 \text{GeV}$.

\end{document}
```

or to use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand{\pt}{p_{T}}
\begin{document}

We analyse all cases of the transverse momentum $\pt$. First, let us
assume that $p_{T} \leq 50 \text{GeV}$.

\end{document}
```

Personally, I prefer the latter because explicit is better than implicit and because this will probably work better with the syntax highlighter in your editor. See also [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro).

Comment: you need to correct the second formula in both cases

Comment: The second way is the correct one. Math should *always* be math. Rather, `siunitx` should be used rather than the disputable `\text`.

Answer (score 4):

The error is because you are nesting two math environments. Change you command definition to:

```
\newcommand{\pt}{\ensuremath{p_{T}}}
```

Comment: Answer from @Zarko contains an additional important information on `\xspace` therefore I change the "Accepted answer".