# Wrap many math macros into `\ensuremath`

Tags: math-mode, macros, loops

I find it more natural refering to `\Phi`, `\alpha`, `\sim`, *etc.* outside math mode the same as inside math mode. *I.e.* writing:

```
Consider \Phi, \alpha{} and \sim{} in the following equation:
\begin{equation}
    \Phi \sim \alpha
\end{equation}
```

Instead of:

```
Consider $\Phi$, $\alpha$ and $\sim$ in the following equation:
\begin{equation}
    \Phi \sim \alpha
\end{equation}
```

My naive approach is to override all the macros I need with their own variant, following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1245705/3719101), with:

```
\let\NPhi\Phi % native phi
\def\Phi{\ensuremath{\NPhi}}
\let\Nalpha\alpha % native alpha
\def\alpha{\ensuremath{\Nalpha}}
\let\Nsim\sim
\def\sim{\ensuremath{\Nsim}}
..
```

But it is quite tedious. How could I loop over that? So that:

```
\magiccommand{
    Phi,
    alpha,
    sim,
    ..}
```

would produce the same result?

Comment: As usual, any time you will shave off with this macro will be spent when you are trying to debug the weird errors you will get because of this.

Comment: @percusse Haha, [of course](https://xkcd.com/1319/) ;)

Comment: Related Question: [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/4301).

Comment: What is better? `\alpha{}` (having to remember to add `{}`) or just `$\alpha$`? I have no doubt it's the latter.

Comment: @PeterGrill related indeed :) Thanks for that. I don't think it's a problem for such macros with no arguments, though, since there will be no semantic to break.

Comment: @egreg I understand. To me, it is not a matter of number of chars or semantics, but a matter of *consistency* (which I feel LaTeX often lacks). (+ for those in the mood for nitpicking, number of chars wins in the occasional case of `\Phi,` because of the comma :P)

Comment: @iago-lito To the contrary, `$\alpha$` *is* consistent, because `\alpha` is a math symbol.

Comment: @egreg I agree. My point is that it is consistent *within a context with much semantics*; *i.e.* a context where I have to make a distinction between "maths symbols" and "non-maths symbols" (this is why I wrote about "semantics"). As a user, all I want is a `\Phi` and there is no such math/nomath semantic distinction in my brain. Thus, in *my* (restrained, semantically-weaker) context, I find `\Phi{}` more consistent :)

Comment: @egreg At the other end of this interesting "__semantics *vs.* consistence__" tradeoff, we could also -distinguish- :every: :word: :like: :this: -depending- :on: :whether: :they: -are- :a: :verb: :or: :not:, which would be consistent in a grammar-caring context, and unconsistent in a more relaxed context where all we want is just typing words, what do you think? ^ ^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is a parser for comma separated values. The following example uses `\comma@parse` of package `kvsetkeys`. The macro automatically strips spaces at the begin and end of the values.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{kvsetkeys}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\EnsureMathDef}[1]{%
  % Throw error, if "\N#1" is already defined.
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname N#1\endcsname{%
    % Save old meaning
    \expandafter
    \let\csname N#1\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname #1\endcsname
    % Define new macro
    \expandafter\edef\csname #1\endcsname{%
      \noexpand\ensuremath{%
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname N#1\endcsname
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\comma@parse{
  Phi,
  alpha,
  sim,
}\EnsureMathDef
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Consider \Phi, \alpha{} and \sim{} in the following equation:
\begin{equation}
    \Phi \sim \alpha
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Without additional package

The macro kernel provides `\@for`. Line ends must be commented to avoid additional spaces.

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\@for\x:=%
  Phi,%
  alpha,%
  sim%
\do{%
  % Throw error if macro with prefix N is already defined.
  \expandafter\@ifdefinable\csname N\x\endcsname{%
    % Save old meaning
    \expandafter
    \let\csname N\x\expandafter\endcsname
    \csname\x\endcsname
    % Define new macro
    \expandafter\edef\csname\x\endcsname{%
      \noexpand\ensuremath{%
        \expandafter\noexpand\csname N\x\endcsname
      }%
    }%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Consider \Phi, \alpha{} and \sim{} in the following equation:
\begin{equation}
    \Phi \sim \alpha
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This does work! I like the version with `\@for` with no additional package, since I don't mind much about trailing `%`. Thanks a lot :)