# Superscript simply refuses to be superscripted

Tags: math-mode, superscripts

I'm getting slightly desperate because the following seemingly simple macro does not do what I want:

```
\newcommand{\Ma}[1][]{\ensuremath{M_{1}^{#1}}\xspace}
Hello $\Ma{a}$.
```

I would expect that `$\Ma{a}$` would result in `a` as a superscript, but id does not. **What's wrong here?**

Comment: #1 is the optional argument, you want either two argument [2] and #2 or should use `[a]` as input. xspace is quite useless here and I wouldn't use \ensuremath either.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You have `\newcommand{\Ma}[1][]{...`. The last pair of brackets mean that the macro has one optional argument, which by default is empty. `#1` refers to this optional argument. To use an optional argument, you need `\Ma[a]`. Because no `[` is seen, the `{a}` is not read as an optional argument, and so is just typeset as normal. Use `\newcommand{\Ma}[1]{...`, or see example below.

Following up on Ulrike's comment, some links about `xspace` and `\ensuremath`:

- [Drawbacks of xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86565/drawbacks-of-xspace/86620#86620)
- [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34830/when-not-to-use-ensuremath-for-math-macro)

And a complete example, with two possible macro definitions.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Ma}[1]{M_{1}^{#1}}
\newcommand{\Mb}[2][1]{M_{#1}^{#2}}
\begin{document}
$\Ma{a}, \Mb{b} \Mb[]{c} \Mb[2]{d}$.
\end{document}
```