# xspace appearing where it shouldn't be

Tags: math-mode, xspace

In this example

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Tt}{\ensuremath{t}}
\begin{document}
We study \Tt as single items.
\end{document}
```

I have defined a `\newcommand` `\Tt` where I use `\ensuremath` so that `\Tt` have a dual capacity to be inserted in plain text and in maths mode. In text however the space before `\Tt` vanishes

[image]

I fix the problem by adding `xspace` (requires `\usepackage{xspace}`):

`\newcommand{\Tt}{\ensuremath{t}\xspace}`.

The outcome is appealing:

[image]

A problem becomes apparent when I write:

```
We study \Tt\Tt pairs.
```

A space has appeared between the `\Tt`'s

[image]

If I would really want a space between the `\Tt`'s I would have added it myself. How to approach this problem?

Comment: If [*don't use `xspace`*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/35864) is not an acceptable answer, you may want to try `\xspaceaddexceptions{\Tt}`.

Comment: @moewe, how exactly? `\Tt` in `\xspaceaddexceptions{\Tt}` disappeared.

Comment: Is there a real reason for not typing `We study $t$ as a single item and $tt$ as a pair`? `\Tt` is three keys as well as $t$, `\Tt\Tt` is six instead of four. Even if you want to define a command (and there are good reasons to), `$\Tt$` is way clearer and less error prone than using `\ensuremath`.

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow. What are you saying with "`\Tt` in `\xspaceaddexceptions{\Tt}` disappeared."? The command should be used once in the preamble to avoid `\xspace` adding the unnecessary space before `\Tt`. You are not supposed to use it instead of `\Tt` in `We study \Tt as single items.`.

Comment: @moewe, adding `\xspaceaddexceptions{\Tt}` in preamble works. Will you supply an answer?

Comment: @egreg, `\Tt` is heavily used in the document and it should be differentiated from `$t$`'s not having the same meaning as `\Tt`. And I simplify my examples. Imagine, `$t^{3}_{a}$`.

Comment: @Viesturs I said that there are indeed good reasons for doing `\newcommand{\Tt}{t}` (so that you can change your mind later about how to represent the object). There is *no* good reason for using `\ensuremath`.

Comment: This is definitely a case where you should  not use `\xspace` (sometimes I regret publishing that package at all:-)

Comment: "If I would really want a space between the \Tt's I would have added it myself." that basically is why `\xspace` isn't useful, it is much simpler to add the space when you need one, than try to tune its automatic guess of when a space is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tell `xspace` not to add a space before `\Tt` with

```
\xspaceaddexceptions{\Tt}
```

As pointed out in [the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459317/xspace-appearing-where-it-shouldnt-be/459322?noredirect=1#comment1155098_459322) by [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) this will stop `xspace` from adding space before `\Tt` in all situations, even if you would otherwise like to see it, say because you have

```
\newcommand\study{\study\xspace}
```

and then

```
We \study \Tt.
```

(David's example.)

Since it has been brought up in comments under the question and under the answer, let me also mention in this answer that it would be preferable not to use `\ensuremath` and `\xspace` in this situation at all. Forcing yourself into math mode where math mode is appropriate has the advantage that you probably won't write something like `\Tt - \Tt` in text mode, which is nearly always not what you wanted. You might save a few keystrokes, but you lose clarity and run the risk of producing unfortunate constructions like `\Tt - \Tt`. Plus if you are forced to use math mode, the issue with macros eating the following space goes away... For reasons not to use `xspace` see also [Drawbacks of xspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/35864), for `\ensuremath` there is [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/35864).

**I strongly recommend you use the `\Ttm` in the example below, i.e. no `\xspace` and no `\ensuremath`.**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xspace}
\newcommand{\Tt}{\ensuremath{t}\xspace}
\xspaceaddexceptions{\Tt}

\newcommand{\Ttm}{t}

\begin{document}
We study \Tt pairs.

We study $\Ttm$ pairs.

We study \Tt\Tt pairs.

We study $\Ttm\Ttm$ pairs.
\end{document}
```

Comment: while this is of course an answer to the question, neither `\ensuremath` nor `\xspace` should be used here, also the exception is saying never to put a space before `\Tt` which isn't really right, if you had `\newcommand\study{\study\xspace}`  then this would mean that `\study \tt` had no space after `study`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh yes, that is a good point, I didn't think of other macros using `\xspace` as well. Since you and egreg both advocate against `\ensuremath` and `\xspace` I have allowed myself to add a short paragraph echoing these sentiments in the answer.

Comment: Some people have created `\xpace` and `\ensuremath` while other people strongly advocate against their use.

Comment: @Viesturs [But at least for `\xspace` the intersection of the set of creators and set of people who don't recommend its use is non empty.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86565/35864) For `\ensuremath` I believe that does not hold.  And `\ensuremath` certainly has its uses, but this is very likely not one of them.

Comment: Plus I don't believe that only the developer/creator of a macro/package should be allowed to discourage its use. What about `\it`, `$$`? Would you only allow Donald Knuth to say anything about this?