# Temporarily turn off a global option

Tags: math-mode, fontspec

See this minimal example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{marathi}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Shobhika}

\begin{document}
    \ensuremath{\frac{१}{२}}
\end{document}
```

I need `no-math` option for a purpose which is not necessary in this MWE, but I also want to type `\frac` command once. How to turn off `no-math` option (which was initially declared globally) for a short scope in the document.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but this usage of `\ensuremath` is wrong.

Comment: Actually I want to use this in a glossary entry. I was getting an error with $$, hence I used `ensuremath`. What is the correct use of it?

Comment: If it gives you errors with `$...$` then removed the `$`.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35877

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `\text`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{marathi}
\setmainfont[Script=Devanagari,Mapping=devanagarinumerals]{Shobhika}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

$\frac{\text{१}}{\text{२}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great. This worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You ask how to temporarily turn off a global option.

In general you have to look at the code (in the class or package) that sets the global option, create a macro that negates that code and also a macro that reinstates the option code. Something along the lines:

```
\documentclass[opta]{...}
\newcommand{\killopta}{...}
\newcommand{\enableopta}{...}
%
\begin{document}
bla bla bla
\killopta % disable option opta
more blas
\enableopta % reenable option opta
yet more blas
\end{document}
```

**ADDITION**

In a comment the OP asked how to deal the the `nomath` option in the `fontspec` package.

I have never used `fontspec` but looking at the `fonspec` code as given in `fontspec-luatex.sty` there is the following code:

```
\DeclareOption {math}    {\bool_gset_true:N \g__fontspec_math_bool }
\DeclareOption {no-math} { \bool_gset_false:N \g__fontspec_math_bool }
```

I would guess that creating two new commands, say `\mathon` and `\mathoff` whose definitions are the same as for the `math` and `no-math` options would enable you to switch between them in the document.

Comment: So for example I want to use `nomath` option provided by package `fontspec`. How to do it with your trick?

Comment: @Niranjan I have extended my answer to try and deal with your extended question. If it does not work then ask a specific question about your problem