# How to treat math mode differently in a custom command?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, macros, conditionals

I use the following command in my preamble for highlighting.

`\newcommand{\zz}[1]{{\color{blue}\sffamily #1}}`

However, I'd like to add the functionality so that I can also include math in it. Currently, statements like

`\zz{Testing, $\mathcal{T}$, $4$, $5$}`

will cause issues during compilation because something about `sffamily` not agreeing with math mode. It will still output the correct PDF, but since I'm getting that error, I feel like I'm doing something fundamentally wrong in the command definition.

I tried looking at using conditionals, however the closest I got was

```
\newcommand{\zz}[1]{
\ifthenelse{\relax\ifmmode}
{\color{blue} #1}
{\color{blue}\sffamily #1}
}
```

which did not work. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If the problem is _only_ with the `$`, a simple solution is to use `\ensuremath{}`. So using  `\zz{Testing, \ensuremath{\mathcal{T}}, \ensuremath{4}, \ensuremath{5}}` should work fine.  But, before get too used to using `\ensuremath{}` everywhere, please do have a look at [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/4301).