# \newcommand with one optional argument: replacement of argument in math environment gives undesired output

Tags: math-mode, macros

I defined a new command,

```
\newcommand{\Test}[1][p]{\ensuremath{n_{\mathrm{dof}}^{\mathrm{Q#1}} }}
```

with one optional argument, which is either 1 or 0. If I call `\Test` without the parameter, I get the desired output, that is the correct subscript Qp. However, calling `\Test{2}` gives the subscript Qp either and the argument 2 is located elsewhere. My intuition is to retrieve Q2 in case of calling `\Test{2}`.
I can add a picture if necessary but I hope it is clear what I refer to.

Is there something I do not encounter correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have misunderstood the syntax of optional parameters: they are delimited by *square* brackets. When you write<sup>1)</sup>

```
\newcommand{\Test}[1][p]{n_{\mathrm{dof}}^{\mathrm{Q#1}}}
```

then `\Test` scans whether a square bracket follows, or not. Your macro should be used either as `\Test` (and then you'll get `Qp` as superscript), or as `\Test[2]`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\Test}[1][p]{n_{\mathrm{dof}}^{\mathrm{Q#1}}}
\begin{document}
$\Test$, $\Test{2}$, $\Test[2]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

<sup>1)</sup> I wouldn't use `\ensuremath` unless my life depended on it; and even in that case I would ponder whether my life is precious enough...

Comment: nice answer (+1), but you suggest to use instead of `\mathrm` that your lije be saved ;-)

Comment: Thank you (+1)! Regarding your footnote, would you share your knowledge why \ensuremath is not a good choice? :-)

Comment: @Simon Some years ago I had a situation where `\ensuremath` was wreaking havoc in such a sneaky way that it took me hours to work out. Admittedly, I was an absolute TeX novice and didn't know how to debug properly. Anyway, I learnt to separate math from text and not to rely on laziness. Have a look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/82917 for some discussion.