# ensuremath, textsf and memoir: the impossible trio

Tags: math-mode, fonts, memoir

I'd like some commands involving `\textsf` to be usable in both math mode and text-mode in a `memoir` document class:

```
Hello \abcd{}, $\abcd{}$.
```

to produce:

[image]

I found a solution involding `\sf` that works for articles, but unfortunately `\sf` works only in `article` and `\textsf` does not work in `\ensuremath`. Any idea how I could solve this problem?

```
\documentclass[]{memoir}

% Fails in both memoir and article
\newcommand*\abcd{\ensuremath{\textsf{ab^{cd}}}}
% Fails in memoir
%\newcommand*\abcd{\ensuremath{{\sf{ab^{cd}}}}}

\begin{document}
Hello \abcd{}, $\abcd{}$
\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

I tried to compare the different propositions of egreg: `\textsuperscript` does not work nicely with `\textsubscript` (`rlap` is dirty and gives bad results often), otherwise `\mathfs` gives decent results (even if I prefer the look of `\textsuperscript` for text.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\newcommand{\versionA}{\mbox{\sffamily ABC\textsuperscript{can}\textsubscript{sup}}}
\newcommand{\versionB}{\mbox{\sffamily ABC\rlap{\textsuperscript{can}}\textsubscript{sup}}}
\newcommand{\versionC}{\ensuremath{\textsf{ABC}^{\textsf{can}}_{\textsf{sup}}}}
\newcommand{\versionD}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{ABC}^{\mathsf{can}}_{\mathsf{sup}}}}
\newcommand{\versionE}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{ABC^{can}_{sup}}}}
\newcommand{\versionF}{\ensuremath{{\sf ABC^{can}_{sup}}}}
\newcommand{\versionAns}{\mbox{\sffamily ABC\textsuperscript{can}}}
\newcommand{\versionBns}{\mbox{\sffamily ABC\rlap{\textsuperscript{can}}}}
\newcommand{\versionCns}{\ensuremath{\textsf{ABC}^{\textsf{can}}}}
\newcommand{\versionDns}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{ABC}^{\mathsf{can}}}}
\newcommand{\versionEns}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{ABC^{can}}}}
\newcommand{\versionFns}{\ensuremath{{\sf ABC^{can}}}}
\begin{document}

\noindent With subscript:\\
\versionA, $\versionA$, \versionAns, $\versionAns$, $\versionAns_\delta$: textsuperscript $\Rightarrow $ not aligned properly\\
\versionB, $\versionB$, \versionBns, $\versionBns$, $\versionBns_\delta$: textsuperscript+rlap $\Rightarrow$ good looking, but rlap removes width so bad result if the lower script has a smaller width\\
\versionC, $\versionC$, \versionCns, $\versionCns$, $\versionCns_\delta$: textsf $\Rightarrow$ too big\\
\versionD, $\versionD$, \versionDns, $\versionDns$, $\versionDns_\delta$: mathsf 3 times $\Rightarrow$ best result, I just find the subscript text to be a bit too low compared to textsuperscript\\
\versionE, $\versionE$, \versionEns, $\versionEns$, $\versionEns_\delta$: mathsf 1 time $\Rightarrow$ okish, just not working with unknown subscript.\\
\versionF, $\versionF$, \versionFns, $\versionFns$, $\versionFns_\delta$: sf (fail with memoir), otherwise like mathsf\\

\end{document}
```

[image]

Zoomed:

[image]

Comment: What's the reason for having commands working both in text and math to begin with?

Comment: Well, they are at the beginning commands that were supposed to work mostly in text mode (because they are names of objects) so I used them as such mostly, but sometimes it is practical to use them in math mode, for instance to add arguments to it, like in $\abcd_{42}$. And `\ensuremath` sounds like a great solution for that, but I was not expecting such breakages... Now, I have dozen of pages to correct if I can't find a quick fix.

Comment: `\textsf` works in math mode  why do you need `\ensuremath` ?(but usually it better to use `\mathsf`

Comment: How is this question related to the memoir class?

Comment: @daleif `\sf` was the only solution that worked in articles, but`\sf` fails with `memoir` class

Comment: @DavidCarlisle because I have superscripts/subscripts.

Comment: yes but that's more or less independent of the sans serif. you can have `\textsf{x}^{\textsf{y}}`  wherever you can have `x^y` so you are just asking for a superscript form that works in text and math. textsf isn't very related and memoir isn't involved at all.

Comment: note `x^{\textsf{y}}` will be the right size if you use `amsmath` package (actually teh `amstext` package that it loads.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Well when I wrote that question I also got confused, I was expecting `\textsf{x^y}` to work exactly like `\textsf{x}^\textsf{y}`, so I though that the error was saying that `\textsf` was simply unusable in math mode.

Comment: no it's saying `^` is unusable in text mode

Comment: `\sf` has been wrong since 1993! (memoir has an option to enable it again, but as others mention it is not the correct way)

Comment: `\sf` will work with the `memoir` class if you use the `oldfontcommands` class option to enable the old deprecated font commands which you should not be using. Any chance of you deleting "memoir" from your question's title?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see no reason for having a command that works in text and in math. See [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/34830/4427) and other threads.

If you ***really*** want it, which I doubt, do

```
\newcommand{\abcd}{\ensuremath{\mathsf{ab}^{\mathsf{cd}}}}
```

If you need that the letters obey the surrounding conditions (italic, for instance), then split `\textsf`:

```
\newcommand{\abcd}{\ensuremath{\textsf{ab}^{\textsf{cd}}}}
```

Of course, a more appropriate solution in this case would be

```
\newcommand{\abcd}{\mbox{\sffamily ab\textsuperscript{cd}}}
```

By the way, `\sf` has been a deprecated command for about 30 years.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just minor remarks: `\sfshape` does not work, I guess you meant `\sffamily`. Then, `\textsuperscript` is not ideal because I also have subscripts and they don't play nicely together. `\textsf` gives too big text (see my comparison in my edit)... so I guess the best result is `\mathsf`. Thanks! It's not as good looking as `\textsubscript`+rlap for texts, but at least it does not fail if subscript is too small.

Comment: Actually, as pointed out in comments (thanks @DavidCarlisle) I realized that loading `amsmath` solves the size issue for `\textsf`.