# Best convention for defining a class of symbols

Tags: macros

Say I'd like to follow a convention in my article, e.g. "Summation indices will be denoted by Latin letters `i, j, k`" or "Free parameters will be denoted by Greek letters `\alpha, \beta, \gamma ...`. I might want to change this convention at any time, so I've been defining new commands for them e.g. `\NewDocumentCommand{\indexi}{i}, ... \indexj, \indexk ...` etc.

Is there some kind of idiomatic way to handle these, as it gets quite cumbersome? Ideally I'd like to do something like define a sequence e.g. `\index: default -> i, 2 -> j, 3 -> k` and refer to them as `\index, \index[2], \index[3]` etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\afterassignment` TeX primitive and simplify the syntax to `\index` or `\index2` or `\index3` etc.

```
\newcount\inum
\def\index{\afterassignment\indexA \inum=0} % the standard LaTeX meaning of \index is re-defined here
\def\indexA{\ifcase\inum i\or i\or j\or k\or l\or m\else x\fi}

$\index,\quad \index1,\quad \index2,\quad \index3$
```

The result is the same as given by mbert.

Comment: Please at least warn about the use of `\index` here. The result will certainly not be the same if somebody also tries to use standard `\index`. The problem might be obvious to you, but it will not be so for everybody.

Comment: IMHO, everybody understand that if the `\index` is used in another meaning in the document then the same control sequence cannot be used in different meaning too. And OP asked for creating `\index` macro. I supposed, that OP doesn't use `\index` in standard meaning, otherwise he would not want to redefine it. And your comment is enough warning.

Comment: In my experience, almost any claim which begins 'everybody understands that $\theta$' is false. The exceptions are not cases where $\theta$ involves technology of any kind.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a bit overkill but you can use an l3 property list to do this. Note you shouldn't use `\index` as the command since that's the command to enter index entries. I use `\myindex` below.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\prop_new:N \g_sudhir_indices_prop
\prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \g_sudhir_indices_prop
  {
    1 = i, 2 = j, 3 = k
  }
\NewDocumentCommand { \myindex } { O{1} }
  { \prop_item:Nn \g_sudhir_indices_prop { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\myindex,\quad \myindex[1],\quad \myindex[2],\quad \myindex[3]$
\end{document}
```

[image: indices]

Answer (score 2):

My original answer addressed how to pull out an indexed item from a sequence. Despite the comments, it only allowed you to pull out a single item at a time. However, it allowed more complex items to be included in the sequence.

In fact, however, you don't want arbitrary items in sequences. You just want to convert an integer into some format in the same way counters are formatted in many other places in LaTeX. That is, this is basically like choosing whether you want your sections labelled with letters or your enumerated items labelled with roman numerals. The only real complication is that Greek letters are not among the default format options. For that case, therefore, we need to add `\sudhir_int_to_greek:n` using the method explained on page 184 of `interface3.pdf`.

```
\myindex[<positive integer>]
```

displays the integer in the current format. By default, this is a small letter from the Latin alphabet. If no argument is given, `1` is used.

```
\setmyindex{<format>}
```

sets the current format. `<format>` should be one of `alph`, `Alph`, `arabic` or `greek`. This can be easily extended following the patterns shown: a simple copy for a standard counter format such as `Alph` or setup from scratch for a case such as `greek`.

I've only provided the first five Greek letters, but you can extend it easily and copy the definition if you'd like to add uppercase Greek or whatever.

Then

```
$\myindex \myindex[1] \myindex[2] \myindex[3]$

\setmyindex{Alph}
$\myindex \myindex[1] \myindex[2] \myindex[3]$

\setmyindex{arabic}
$\myindex \myindex[1] \myindex[2] \myindex[3]$

\setmyindex{greek}
$\myindex \myindex[1] \myindex[2] \myindex[3]$

\setmyindex{alph}
$\myindex \myindex[1] \myindex[2] \myindex[3]$
```

will produce

[image: integer representations]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/700165/ 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \sudhir_myindex:n
{
  \sudhir_int_to_alph:n { #1 }
}
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Nn \sudhir_setmyindex:n 
{
  \cs_set_eq:Nc \sudhir_myindex:n { sudhir_int_to_#1:n } 
}
\cs_new:Npn \sudhir_int_to_greek:n #1
{% interface3.pdf page 184
  \int_to_symbols:nnn { #1 } { 5 }
  {
    { 1 } { \ensuremath{\alpha} }
    { 2 } { \ensuremath{\beta} }
    { 3 } { \ensuremath{\gamma} }
    { 4 } { \ensuremath{\delta} }
    { 5 } { \ensuremath{\epsilon} }
  }
}
\cs_new_eq:NN \sudhir_int_to_arabic:n \int_to_arabic:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \sudhir_int_to_alph:n \int_to_alph:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \sudhir_int_to_Alphc:n \int_to_Alph:n
\NewDocumentCommand \myindex { O {1} }
{%
  \sudhir_myindex:n { #1 }
}
\NewDocumentCommand \setmyindex { m }
{
  \sudhir_setmyindex:n { #1 }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
$\myindex \myindex[1] \myindex[2] \myindex[3]$

\setmyindex{Alph}
$\myindex \myindex[1] \myindex[2] \myindex[3]$

\setmyindex{arabic}
$\myindex \myindex[1] \myindex[2] \myindex[3]$

\setmyindex{greek}
$\myindex \myindex[1] \myindex[2] \myindex[3]$

\setmyindex{alph}
$\myindex \myindex[1] \myindex[2] \myindex[3]$

\end{document}
```

Comment: @AlanMunn I just came back to delete this. But, actually, I'm not outputting more than one element. I just think this is a bad way to do this.

Comment: Scnr: iirc there has been some discussion about `\ensuremath`.  ;-)

Comment: @UlrichDiez What's `Scnr`? Is `\ensuremath` another thing I don't know about? Re. `\int_to_symbols:nnn`. That's my understanding. At least, I don't know if that reflects the implementation exactly, but it is designed to work as if that is what's going on. So (from the docs) `27` is mapped to `aa` by `\int_to_alph:n`, which would be implemented by `\int_to_symbols:nnn { #1 } { 26 } { {1}{a} {2}{b} ...}`.

Comment: @cfr  scnr = sorry, could not resist. ;-)  || Regarding `\ensuremath` you mght be interested in egreg's answer to [When not to use \ensuremath for math macro?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35877/118714)

Comment: @UlrichDiez You are probably right about the OP's usage. It would not be at all unusual for me to want to use something like `<term>\textsubscript{<index>}`. Strictly speaking, I suppose `<index>` should use `\textgreek{}` if a Greek letter is wanted, but it doesn't really seem necessary when the letters are being used as symbols more than anything else. I don't think it's unreasonable to use `\ensuremath{}` in such a case. Indeed, I initially set it up with `$...$` before realising the OP probably wanted to use this in maths mode. That possibility had not initially occurred to me.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Is also needed for what exactly?

Comment: @UlrichDiez OK. If this was intended to provide a representation of any natural number, you'd need that. But isn't it just being used as an identifier? If I needed to distinguish 31 senses of a term, I wouldn't do it with subscripts anyway. More than 5, sure - that was just an example - but there's a limit to what you can reasonably keep track of or expect your readers to keep track of. I have the distinct feeling we're talking about completely different things ....

Comment: I was talking about how `\int_to_symbols:nnn{⟨integer expression⟩} {⟨total symbols⟩}{⟨value to symbol mapping⟩}` seems to work: Converts the result of ⟨integer expression⟩ to representation in positional number system with base ⟨total symbols⟩ and digits 1.. ⟨total symbols⟩ and then maps each digit according to ⟨value to symbol mapping⟩.

Comment: @UlrichDiez Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 2):

Give symbolic names to your classes of objects and then you can associate commands to them.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\defineclass}{mm}
 {% #1 = class name, #2 = symbols
  \seq_new:c { g_aps_class_#1_seq }
  \seq_gset_from_clist:cn { g_aps_class_#1_seq } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\useclass}{mm}
 {% #1 = control sequence, #2 = class
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{O{1}}
   {
    \seq_item:cn { g_aps_class_#2_seq } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% define your classes
\defineclass{ijk}{i,j,k,l}
\defineclass{greek}{\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta,\varepsilon}

% associate classes with commands
\useclass{\sumind}{ijk}
\useclass{\freepar}{greek}

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_{\sumind\ge1}\sumind x^{\sumind}=x\sum_{\sumind[2]\ge0}(\sumind[2]+1)x^{\sumind[2]}
\]

\[
\freepar+\freepar[2]
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is already a command `\index` in LaTeX 2ε, so don't let us use that name but let's name the commands `\Summationindex` resp. `\FreeParameter`.

expl3's `\tl_item:nn` let's you select an item of a token list. You can use that for defining mapping from numbers to symbols:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand\Summationindex{O{1}}{
  \tl_item:nn {
                {a}{b}{c}{d}{e}{f}{g}{h}{i}{j}{k}{l}{m}{n}{o}{p}{q}{r}{s}{t}{u}{v}{w}{x}{y}{z}
              } 
              {((#1)+8)} % <- Let's add 8 so that \Summationindex[1] yields i.
}
\NewDocumentCommand\FreeParameter{O{1}}{
  \tl_item:nn {
                {\alpha}{\beta}{\gamma}{\delta}{\epsilon}% probably \varepsilon
                {\zeta}{\eta}{\theta}% probably \vartheta?
                {\iota}{\kappa}{\lambda}{\mu}{\nu}{\xi}{o}{\pi}{\rho}% probably \varrho
                {\sigma}{\tau}{\upsilon}{\phi}% probably \varphi
                {\chi}{\psi}{\omega}%
              } 
              {(#1)}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Testing \verb|\Summationindex[-7] to \Summationindex[18]|:

\bigskip

\noindent\verb|$\Summationindex$|: $\Summationindex$

\bigskip

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}%
\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[-7]$|: $\Summationindex[-7]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[-6]$|: $\Summationindex[-6]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[-5]$|: $\Summationindex[-5]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[-4]$|: $\Summationindex[-4]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[-3]$|: $\Summationindex[-3]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[-2]$|: $\Summationindex[-2]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[-1]$|: $\Summationindex[-1]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[0]$|: $\Summationindex[0]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[1]$|: $\Summationindex[1]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[2]$|: $\Summationindex[2]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[3]$|: $\Summationindex[3]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[4]$|: $\Summationindex[4]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[5]$|: $\Summationindex[5]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[6]$|: $\Summationindex[6]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[7]$|: $\Summationindex[7]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[8]$|: $\Summationindex[8]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[9]$|: $\Summationindex[9]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[10]$|: $\Summationindex[10]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[11]$|: $\Summationindex[11]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[12]$|: $\Summationindex[12]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[13]$|: $\Summationindex[13]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[14]$|: $\Summationindex[14]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[15]$|: $\Summationindex[15]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[16]$|: $\Summationindex[16]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[17]$|: $\Summationindex[17]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[18]$|: $\Summationindex[18]$&%
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Testing \verb|\FreeParameter[1] to \FreeParameter[24]|:

\bigskip

\noindent\verb|$\FreeParameter$|: $\FreeParameter$

\bigskip

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}%
\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[1]$|: $\FreeParameter[1]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[2]$|: $\FreeParameter[2]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[3]$|: $\FreeParameter[3]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[4]$|: $\FreeParameter[4]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[5]$|: $\FreeParameter[5]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[6]$|: $\FreeParameter[6]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[7]$|: $\FreeParameter[7]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[8]$|: $\FreeParameter[8]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[9]$|: $\FreeParameter[9]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[10]$|: $\FreeParameter[10]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[11]$|: $\FreeParameter[11]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[12]$|: $\FreeParameter[12]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[13]$|: $\FreeParameter[13]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[14]$|: $\FreeParameter[14]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[15]$|: $\FreeParameter[15]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[16]$|: $\FreeParameter[16]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[17]$|: $\FreeParameter[17]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[18]$|: $\FreeParameter[18]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[19]$|: $\FreeParameter[19]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[20]$|: $\FreeParameter[20]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[21]$|: $\FreeParameter[21]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[22]$|: $\FreeParameter[22]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[23]$|: $\FreeParameter[23]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[24]$|: $\FreeParameter[24]$\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

You can also consider implementing mapping from number to symbol via expl3's `\int_case:nnF` where implementing raising an error-message in case a mapping is not defined is more easy.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Use expl3-infrastructure for providing error-message in case mapping from number to
% symbol is undefined:
% ........................................................................................
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_type_prop { MyStuff } {}
\prop_gput:Nnn \g_msg_module_name_prop { MyStuff } {Macro-Defined-In-Preamble:}
\msg_new:nnnn {MyStuff} 
              {No mapping defined}
              {Macro~#1:~No~mapping~defined~for~number~#2.}
              {Make~sure~that~the~definition~of~macro~#1~also~provides~a~mapping~for~the~number~#2.}
\cs_new:Npn \NoMappingDefinedError #1#2 {
  \exp_args:Nne \use:nn {
    \msg_error:nnnn {MyStuff} {No mapping defined}
   }{{\iow_char:N \\ \cs_to_str:N#1}}{#2}
}%
% ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\NewDocumentCommand\Summationindex{O{1}}{
  \int_case:nnF {(#1)}
  {
    {-7}{a}  {-6}{b}  {-5}{c}  {-4}{d}  {-3}{e}  {-2}{f}  {-1}{g}   {0}{h}   {1}{i}
     {2}{j}   {3}{k}   {4}{l}   {5}{m}   {6}{n}   {7}{o}   {8}{p}   {9}{q}  {10}{r}
    {11}{s}  {12}{t}  {13}{u}  {14}{v}  {15}{w}  {16}{x}  {17}{y}  {18}{z}
  }
  {\NoMappingDefinedError{\Summationindex}{(#1)}}
}

\NewDocumentCommand\FreeParameter{O{1}}{
  \int_case:nnF {(#1)}
  {
    {1}{\alpha}     {2}{\beta}      {3}{\gamma}     {4}{\delta}
    {5}{\epsilon}% probably \varepsilon
    {6}{\zeta}      {7}{\eta}       
    {8}{\theta}% probably \vartheta?
    {9}{\iota}     {10}{\kappa}    {11}{\lambda}   {12}{\mu}
    {13}{\nu}      {14}{\xi}       {15}{o}         {16}{\pi}  
    {17}{\rho}% probably \varrho
    {18}{\sigma}   {19}{\tau}      {20}{\upsilon} 
    {21}{\phi}% probably \varphi
    {22}{\chi}    {23}{\psi}       {24}{\omega}
  }
  {\NoMappingDefinedError{\FreeParameter}{(#1)}}
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

Testing \verb|\Summationindex[-7] to \Summationindex[18]|:

\bigskip

\noindent\verb|$\Summationindex$|: $\Summationindex$

\bigskip

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}%
\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[-7]$|: $\Summationindex[-7]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[-6]$|: $\Summationindex[-6]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[-5]$|: $\Summationindex[-5]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[-4]$|: $\Summationindex[-4]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[-3]$|: $\Summationindex[-3]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[-2]$|: $\Summationindex[-2]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[-1]$|: $\Summationindex[-1]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[0]$|: $\Summationindex[0]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[1]$|: $\Summationindex[1]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[2]$|: $\Summationindex[2]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[3]$|: $\Summationindex[3]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[4]$|: $\Summationindex[4]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[5]$|: $\Summationindex[5]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[6]$|: $\Summationindex[6]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[7]$|: $\Summationindex[7]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[8]$|: $\Summationindex[8]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[9]$|: $\Summationindex[9]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[10]$|: $\Summationindex[10]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[11]$|: $\Summationindex[11]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[12]$|: $\Summationindex[12]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[13]$|: $\Summationindex[13]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[14]$|: $\Summationindex[14]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[15]$|: $\Summationindex[15]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[16]$|: $\Summationindex[16]$\\\hline
\verb|$\Summationindex[17]$|: $\Summationindex[17]$&%
\verb|$\Summationindex[18]$|: $\Summationindex[18]$&%
\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

Testing \verb|\FreeParameter[1] to \FreeParameter[24]|:

\bigskip

\noindent\verb|$\FreeParameter$|: $\FreeParameter$

\bigskip

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}%
\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[1]$|: $\FreeParameter[1]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[2]$|: $\FreeParameter[2]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[3]$|: $\FreeParameter[3]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[4]$|: $\FreeParameter[4]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[5]$|: $\FreeParameter[5]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[6]$|: $\FreeParameter[6]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[7]$|: $\FreeParameter[7]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[8]$|: $\FreeParameter[8]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[9]$|: $\FreeParameter[9]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[10]$|: $\FreeParameter[10]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[11]$|: $\FreeParameter[11]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[12]$|: $\FreeParameter[12]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[13]$|: $\FreeParameter[13]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[14]$|: $\FreeParameter[14]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[15]$|: $\FreeParameter[15]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[16]$|: $\FreeParameter[16]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[17]$|: $\FreeParameter[17]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[18]$|: $\FreeParameter[18]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[19]$|: $\FreeParameter[19]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[20]$|: $\FreeParameter[20]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[21]$|: $\FreeParameter[21]$\\\hline
\verb|$\FreeParameter[22]$|: $\FreeParameter[22]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[23]$|: $\FreeParameter[23]$&%
\verb|$\FreeParameter[24]$|: $\FreeParameter[24]$\\\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]